# Using "this" with javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am attempting to simplify some code for a tic tac toe game.

Every sector of the grid has the class "tictactoe" and an id specifiying their region e.g "upleft". My thought is that `onclick` within the html element, will call a JavaScript function which will display an X in that space.

So here is what I have:

HTML Element:

```
<td id="upleft" onclick="displayX()" class="tictactoe"></td>
```

JavaScript/JQuery function:

```
                 function displayX()
                {
                        $('#upleft').text("x");
                }
```

Basically I want to change the function to using "this" instead of "#upleft"

However when I do this:

```
                function displayX()
                {
                        $(this).text("x");
                }
```

No text is displayed is the grid specified upleft. Firstly, does the "this" function, place the code into the id specified? And secondly, how can I remedy this issue?

Comment: $('table').on('click','td',function(){$(this).text('x');});

Comment: You could use `onclick="displayX.call(this)"`, however it would be far easier to maintain if you removed the onclick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the **DOM element** as a `argument to the function` when you define the **function Inline**

```
onclick="displayX(this)" 


function displayX(elem)
{
    $(elem).text("x");
}
```

It's a bad idea to write **inline javascript..** .. **Avoid it..**

Better to attach the event in the `javascripe file..`

```
$("td").on('click', function () {
   $(this).text("x");
});
```

Comment: Why is it necessarily a bad idea to use "inline javascript"?

Comment: @ZAX You can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick/12627478#12627478 for more about why not to use inline scripts.

Comment: You have many disadvantages..  Your HTML page becomes heavy , caching is not possible, bad antipattern  .. Also check this article http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: Sorry, last question for clarification, if I were to use the second method, not inline java, and I placed my class name .tictactoe for the on click handler, the this would identify the actual id (spot on the grid) that I wish to add the X to correct?

Comment: @ZAX Yes, using `this` would be the actual element that is clicked.

Comment: yup .. `$('.tictactoe').on('click' , function(){ // Here this corresponds to the td which was clicked that has the class called tictactoe }`

Comment: Alright, ran into one more issue, then I've got it done.... To further simplify and keep track of which spaces have been clicked to check for a winner, I need to know which spot was clicked so I need the id. I cannot find a this.getName() function available in JavaScript or something similar that will return the id. Thoughts on how to get the id name or some other identifier I might be able to use?

Comment: @ZAX You should post that as another question. This question is answered.

Comment: you can just use `this.id` , inside the event .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery you can bind the handler using `.on` see below,

```
$("#upleft").on('click', function () {
   $(this).text("x");
});
```

This is better than using `onclick` on the html. If you still want to use the `onclick` then you need to pass the `this`. See below,

and then in your js,

```
 function displayX(obj) {
    $(obj).text("x");
 }
```

Comment: @JasonSperske Me neither, but I stopped asking why.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the event using jquery.  Do

```
$("#upleft").click(function(event){displayX(event)});

function displayX(event)
{
    $(event.target).html("X");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML element to pass the `this` :

```
<td id="upleft" onclick="displayX(this)" class="tictactoe"></td>
```

And then modify your function to :

```
function displayX(el)
{
    $(el).text("x");
}
```