# call onclick attribute programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of `<a>` tags on a page that look something like

```
 <a href="#" id="001" onclick="fnaaa();" >...</a>
  ...
 <a href="#" id="002" onclick="fnaba();" >...</a>
  ...
 <a href="#" id="003" onclick="fncda();" >...</a>


 //sometimes maybe like this
 <a href="#" id="004" onclick="fnagg(); return false;" >...</a>
  ...
```

Now I have the id passed to the page as a query string , so I originally wanted to do something like

```
$('a[id="' + id + '"]').click();
$('a[id="' + id + '"]').trigger("click");
```

it turns out both of those are not allowed , so if I have the id , how can I call the function that is written in the onclick attribute? I know I can probably get it like this

```
var funcToCall = $('a[id="' + id + '"]').attr('onclick');
```

but how do I call this funcToCall?  remembering that funcToCall may be more then just a function name ex. "fnagg(); return false;"

Comment: no, I do not know what onclick attribut will be on any given <a> tag, I can only find the <a> by id , and want the function that is in that specific onclick

Comment: You could do `$('a[id="' + id + '"]').click();
$('a[id="' + id + '"]').trigger("click");` If you bind event handlers using jQuery function. Read more about the differences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick/12627478#12627478

Comment: You can try like this setTimeout(funcToCall+"()",0);

Comment: This seems like a poor design decision.  What are each of these links doing? For instance, what does `fnaaa()` do?

Comment: I posted a great example please see it on this page 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532182/how-can-i-get-the-function-bound-to-an-onclick-attribute/25532401#25532401

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the ID attribute has [some restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/54420), one being that it must start with a letter.  After you fix that, I would recommend *not* using an inline `onclick` handler.

```
$("#ID_HERE").click(function(e) {
  fnaaa();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then you can trigger it easily:

```
$("#ID_HERE").triggerHandler("click");
```

However, if you absolutely **must** use the ugly onclick, you can invoke it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/CfAYm/):

```
<a id="foo" href="#" onclick="alert('test');">Test</a>
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.onclick();
```

Comment: thanks , those are not my real id's , I just trying to simplify for an example .   so people could see what I am trying to do - get the inline onclick attribute to be called dynamically while only knowing the id

Comment: If you'd like to still use jQuery to select the element (for instance, if you want to select based off of something other than ids), you could trigger the onclick handler with `$(selector)[0].onclick();`

Comment: Im getting Object [object Object] has no method 'onclick'  with the jquery versioin   $(selector)[0].onclick();

Comment: if you use addEventListener() you will not be getting any errors. onclick() is an attribute of the element so you can only assign one click action. Where addEventListener() you assign as many listeners to as many actions to any element you want.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `onclick` attribute to bind the handler. Try like below,

```
document.getElementById(id).click();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kpvKG/

Comment: @ScottSelby What? I think, You have a typo in that demo. Check the attribute `id`.. in that demo you have it as `d` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PJDxV/)

```
function fnagg()
{
    alert('fired');
}
$(function(){
    eval("var funcToCall=function(){"+$('#004').attr("onclick")+"}");
funcToCall();
});
```

Comment: @Vega, You are correct, but it's the only way I know of to wrap a string in a function like the question is requesting.  It's not really always evil...per the top voted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

For the html

```
<a href="#" class="dynamicFuncs" id="my001" data-funcName="myFunc">test</a>
```

And for the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dynamicFuncs").on('click', function(){
        var theFunc = $(this).attr('data-funcName');
        window[theFunc]();
    })
});

var myFunc = function() {
    alert('me');
};
```

Answer (score -2):

It's best to use ***addEventListener()***. You can add all types of events. example: "click","mousemove" and many more. the false at the end is to stop the event from traversing up the DOM tree. By setting the 3rd property to true the event will continue to traverse the DOM tree so that parent elements will also receive the event. This also makes removing events just as simple as adding events using ***removeEventListener()***.

**adding event**

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture)
```

**removing event**

```
element.removeEventListener(event, function, useCapture)
```

**event:**  Required. A String that specifies the name of the event.

**function:**   Required. Specifies the function to run when the event occurs.

**useCapture**  Optional. A Boolean value that specifies whether the event should be executed in the capturing or in the bubbling phase.

**Possible values:**

**true** - The event handler is executed in the capturing phase

**false**- Default. The event handler is executed in the bubbling phase

This example requires no JavaScript libraries. This is just plain old JavaScript and will work in every browser with nothing extra needed.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>exampe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="test" href="">test</a>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert('hello world');
        }, false);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**You can read more about this with the following links:**

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-addeventlistener-with-examples/
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

---

If you would like to use JQuery methods to handle a click event you can do the following.

**Using .click()**

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

More info here: https://api.jquery.com/click/

**Using .on()**

```
$("#target").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/on/