# onclick added with Tampermonkey is not calling the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, tampermonkey

If I create a div programmatically with Tampermonkey:

HTML:

```
<div onclick="myfunc()"/>
```

script:

```
function myfunc() { alert("clicked"); }
```

then click on the div; `myfunc` is not called in my script.

How can I get this to work?

(I use TM/jQuery to add the div to a page and I would like to attach some functionality to it. I assume I have to redirect the function call in the HTML to the proper place. I also use `GM_` functions so I can't just insert the code directly.)

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that since you're setting the attribute to a string, it's evaluating the string in the target-page scope, which doesn't have a `myfunc` function.  `myfunc` resides in the userscript scope.

As a general rule, you should [never use `onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478/331508) anyway, but this goes triple for userscripts.

Make the element easily selectable, like:

```
<div id="gmMyDiv"></div>
```

Then, either use [the `addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), like this:

```
function myfunc (zEvent) {
    alert ("clicked"); 
}

var myDiv   = document.querySelector ("#gmMyDiv");
if (myDiv) {
    myDiv.addEventListener ("click", myfunc , false);
}
```

Or since you are using jQuery:

```
function myfunc (zEvent) {
    alert ("clicked"); 
}

$("#gmMyDiv").click (myfunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### assign a field to the function in the "window" object

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Content Script Example, grant none
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function helper() {
    alert('helper');
}

window.helper2 = helper;

element.innerHTML = "<button onclick='window.helper2()'>Click Me</button>" ;
```

Credits: https://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection