# Insert elements into a form with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, greasemonkey

I'm a novice programmer trying to automate an extremely redundant task at work.
I want to insert some form elements and a text button, but I can't find the correct way to do it.

Here's what I have:

```
//function stuff

var searchyText = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
var searchyDiv = document.createElement("P");
    searchyDiv.innerHTML="<p><a href='#' onClick='searchyTimeGo()'>Click to Search</a></p>";

document.forms[0] ... ?

//    document.insertBefore(searchyDiv, document.forms[0]);
//    document.insertBefore(searchyText, searchyDiv);
```

The question mark is where I got lost, and the comments at the bottom are the failed results of my attempts so far.

I just can't get the text to show up on the page. I've looked at a few video tutorials and realized that I know exactly squat about nodes. There's only one form on the page.

I've gotten "undefined" to write itself in a few times -- when I tried to concatenate the raw HTML to the `form[0].innerHTML`.
I felt dirty and ugly for even trying that, and it still didn't work.

I'm aware that the `onClick` method I've included above will probably fail, but I know how to fix that.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your szenario?

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

- Is there a possibility that the form is getting added via AJAX (javascript)?
- Use [`document.querySelector()`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), or else [jQuery](http://jquery.com/),  to get the form (or just about anything else).  This gives you the flexible power of [CSS selectors](http://fmbip.com/litmus/#css3-selectors).
- For a `<p>` element, don't set the `innerHTML` to another `<p>`
- Is `searchyTimeGo()` defined by the page or by your script?  If by you, then [never](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232:_Event_Handlers), [*ever*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick/12627478#12627478), use `onclick` (or similar).
- It's named `searchyDiv` but you are creating a paragraph (`<p>`).
- It looks like you are trying to add the elements before the form, not into it?
- Use DOM methods.  Avoid using `innerHTML`, as a rule.

Putting it all together your code would be (assuming no AJAX):

```
//-- This gets the FIRST form.
var targForm    = document.querySelector ("form");
if (targForm) {
    var searchyText = document.createElement ("TEXTAREA");
    var searchyDiv  = document.createElement ("DIV");
    var searchyPghp = document.createElement ("P");
    var searchyBtn  = document.createElement ("A");

    searchyBtn.textContent  = "Click to Search";
    searchyBtn.href         = "#";

    searchyBtn.addEventListener ("click", searchyTimeGo,   false);

    searchyDiv.appendChild  (searchyPghp);
    searchyPghp.appendChild (searchyBtn);

    targForm.parentNode.insertBefore (searchyText, targForm);
    targForm.parentNode.insertBefore (searchyDiv, targForm);
}
else {
    alert ("No form found on the page!");
}

function searchyTimeGo () {
    //- DO WHATEVER, HERE.
    console.log ("Search button clicked");
}
```

---

Or **a complete script** showing the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) way:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add custom form elements
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var firstForm = $("form:first");
if (firstForm.length) {
    firstForm.insertBefore (
          '<textarea id="gmMyTextArea"></textarea>'
        + '<div id="gmMySrchDiv"><p><a href="#">Click to Search</a></p></div>'
    );

    $("#gmMySrchDiv > p > a").on ("click", searchyTimeGo);
}
else {
    alert ("No form found on the page!");
}

function searchyTimeGo () {
    //- DO WHATEVER, HERE.
    console.log ("Search button clicked");
}
```