# How to combine SHIFT key with another key

Tags: javascript, html

In my code:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",doKeyDown);
function doKeyDown(e)
{
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    var str = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    console.log(str+":"+e.keyCode);
    var tune = new Audio();
    switch(str)
    {
        case 'Q':
            tune = new Audio("Assets/Tune/C.mp3");
            tune.play();
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to make the input <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> so the audio can be played.

I have tried `case 'SHIFT+B':`  but it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: We need more context. What is `str`? This question isn't really answerable as-is. Ideally, your post should include enough code to entirely replicate your problem.

Comment: Do you use **jQuery**?

Comment: I've edit the code, basically I want to make an input using SHIFT+B to play the sound. I'm trying to make virtual piano

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming because you want Shift + B that this is within a keydown event or something? So you should have access to the event like

```
function onKeyPress(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if(evt.shiftKey) {
        var str = evt.keyCode;
        switch(str)
        {
            //Since we are using the KeyCode, use the ascii value for capital B. 
            case 66:
                tune = new Audio("Assets/Tune/ASharp'.mp3");
                tune.play();
                break;
            default: //Have a default logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I want to press SHIFT+B so the audio will be played. Thanks for the answer

Comment: do I need to put window.addEventListener("keyPress",onKeyPress); before function onKeyPress(e) ?

Comment: yes, you need to attach the function as to an event listener in whichever way you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255283/the-best-way-to-add-eventlistener-to-an-element

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction(event);">

<script>
function myFunction(event) {
    //keyCode for B = 66
    if(event.keyCode == 66 && event.shiftKey) {
      //Your Code
    }
}
</script>
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8pb69uqt/1/)

Comment: @KikujaVonic Please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: This answer was just edited once to add a working FIDDLE. Looks like DOWNVOTERS are awake for no reason.