# Javascript Uncaught Reference error Function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

[Check the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSHQD/) to see the failure occurring.

When I add Data (Even if I leave it empty) to the text box and try to click "Add" it doesn't do anything.

Opening the Chrome and Firefox console both give me the same error, it says `"changeText2()" is not defined`.

How can I fix this? I've ran into this error several times and mostly it had really weird workarounds, but I am not sure as to the method for avoiding it or what I'm even doing wrong.

It seems removing the global variable declarations fixes it most of the time, however, I need them in this case and would rather know why and how this error occurs.

**Javascript:**

```
var list = document.getElementById('deliveryIdArray');
var names = [];

function changeText2() {
    var deliveryIdentification = document.getElementById('deliveryIdentification').value;
    names.push(deliveryIdentification);//simply add new name to array;
    //array changed re-render list
    renderList();
}

function renderList(){
    while (list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
    //create each li again
    for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(names[i]));
        var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("remove"));
        removeButton.setAttribute('onClick','removeName('+i+')');
        entry.appendChild(removeButton);
        list.appendChild(entry);
    }
}


function removeName(nameindex){
    names.splice(nameindex,1);
    //array changed re-render list
    renderList();
}

function getDeliveries(){
    return names;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<b>Number(s): </b>
    <input id = "deliveryIdentification" name = "deliveryIdentification" type = "text" size = "16" maxlength = "30">

    <!-- Array Area Creation -->
    <input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Add' />

    <ol id="deliveryIdArray">
    </ol>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vSHQD/

Comment: Change the wrapping in the fiddle (menu at the left) to "No wrap - in head".

Comment: @dystroy Causes errors because elements don't exist yet ;)

Comment: this will helpful to you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In JSFiddle, when you set the wrapping to "onLoad" or "onDomready", the functions you define are only defined inside that block, and cannot be accessed by outside event handlers.

Easiest fix is to change:

```
function something(...)
```

To:

```
window.something = function(...)
```

Comment: This works. http://jsfiddle.net/vSHQD/1/ updated fiddle showing it working. Thank you for the fast and correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Change the wrapping from **"`onload`"** to **"`No wrap - in <body>`"**

The function defined has a different scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular.js then functions imbedded into HTML, such as `onclick="function()"` or `onchange="function()"`. They will not register. You need to make the change events in javascript. Such as:

```
$('#exampleBtn').click(function() {
  function();
});
```

Comment: Worked for me. Think it's Jquery vs Javascript mistake