# Uncaught ReferenceError: printProducts is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting this error when i inspected the element of my button. The button is suppose to give a print view to page.

HTML Code:

```
<button class = "hidden-print" onclick = "printProducts()">Print Products</button>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function printProducts(){
window.print();
}
```

Attached here is my code live in jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/PochMendoza/scj0q0dk/

Comment: You've a scope issue, `printProducts` is wrapped in onload function

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I've just given the jsFiddle to simulate the problem. Can't seem to get the solution. What am i missing? Is there anything i can do to make my button work? @Teemu

Comment: No? Your [code works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/w3ddjk38/), when not wrapped in onload function. If you've this issue with your real code, then you've to provide the real code relevant to issue.

Comment: that is the code. when i execute the button it doesn't work. could you give me a JSFiddle link that shows that this kind of code works? @Teemu

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza I have added an answer that works with a link to JSFiddle

Comment: thank you, i would try your answer. @Matthew Cliatt

Comment: code still does not work when i apply the code to the web app. it does not show an error message when i inspect it, but the function still does not work. @Matthew Cliatt

Comment: Have you looked in the developer console?

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza I have added what you need to do to fix the code and make it work for your web app. Just look at my answer for the update

Comment: Pocholo, Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

> "In JSFiddle, when you set the wrapping to "onLoad" or "onDomready", the functions you define are only defined inside that block, and cannot be accessed by outside event handlers."
>
> Easiest fix is to change:
>
> `function something(...)`
>
> To:
>
> `window.something = function(...)`
>
> ---[Niet The Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23676636/2542856)

---

For your example, you want to define the `onclick` method of a button. That's really easy with JavaScript, we just need to give the button an `id` in the HTML, so that we can find it in our JavaScript code.

Change this:

```
<button class = "hidden-print" onclick = "printProducts()">Print Products</button>
```

To this:

```
<button id="myButton" class="hidden-print">Print Products</button>
```

Note that we no longer need the `onclick="printProducts()"` part anymore.

Now we need to set the `printProducts` function to run when the button is clicked. This can be done like so:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = printProducts;
```

**Start edit**
This code needs to be placed in the `onload` function though, to properly run.
Do that like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = printProducts;
}
```

**End edit**

And the `printProducts` function remains the same.

---

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scj0q0dk/3/)

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = printProducts;

function printProducts(){
 window.print();
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" class="hidden-print">Print Products</button>
```