# onclick event not running named function when clicked

Tags: javascript

I was expecting the FBLogin onclick to run the below query, but noting is happening. What have I missed which means this isn't working as expected?

I believe this is an issue with my onlick event and not the function itself.

```
<a href="#" onclick="FBLogin();" 
role="button" class="btn btn-successFbLi btn-lg fa fa-facebook"</i> 
Sign in with Facebook</a></button><br>
```

Function

```
function FBLogin() {
//Fb app information//

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });

//rest of function here etc//


}
```

Comment: Is this related to java somehow/

Comment: the code you posted will do nothing - how do you know FBLogin isn't being executed?

Comment: "But nothing is happening": does that mean the event handler is not fen called? How do you know that? What have you done to debug the issue? My guess is that the handler is called after `fbAsyncInit` was already executed.

Comment: Yes the event handler is not being called

Comment: @Dano007 — You keep making that assertion, but we're asking how you establish that. Why do you think it isn't being run?

Comment: `</a></button>` — Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/). You can't have an anchor inside a button.

Comment: @FelixKling fair point, how could the handler be called after fbAsyncInit though if thats within the handler?

Comment: What I meant was that the process that looks at `fbAsyncInit` and tries to call it already ran.

Comment: @FelixKling good point, actually that helped unpick the overall issue and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in the code you provided.

- wrong anchor tag
- extra closing tags (`<i>`, `<button>`)

The major changes I made in the code:

- removed `onclick` attribute
- added event listener in javascript

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L3mqjsL/1/)

Here is the snippet.

```js
function FBLogin() {
  //Fb app information//
  alert("WORKING");
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
      appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.3'
    });

    //rest of function here etc//


  }
}

document.getElementById('login').addEventListener("click", FBLogin);
```

```html
<a id='login' href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-successFbLi btn-lg fa fa-facebook">
Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

More about Event Listeners [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: `<a href="#" role="button"` — Don't use links that pretend to be buttons, use buttons.

Comment: Care to explain why the inline event handler does not work?

Comment: using inline event handlers should be avoided. Source : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/4338417. I stopped using inline event handlers after reading this answer.

Comment: It's true that they should be avoided, but they are not the source of all problems. You said the OP **needs** to change it, but I don't see why. Blindly changing things hoping it will fix an issue is not a reasonable approach. As you can see, your fiddle works fine with inline event handlers as well: http://jsfiddle.net/6hgk4q32/. So there is certainly no *need* to change this.

Comment: I changed the statement in my answer. I agree that the code should not be changed blindly. Its just that when I made changes to OP's code, I used `addEventListener` approach as it makes the code a little better.