# How to get the text from a p by clicking its div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to click in the div or the img and get the text of the p inside it to go in another list.

```
 <div onClick="add_basket(this);" class="menu-item burger"> <img  src="img\McDo\bigmac.png"> <p>Big Mac</p> </div>
  <div onClick="add_basket(this);" class="menu-item burger"> <img  src="img\McDo\doubleqp.png"> <p>Double Quarter Pounder</p> </div>


   <ul class="basket" id="basket-mcdo">
    <li>Order</li>
    <li>Mcdo</li>
  </ul>
```

and i have a lot of others like that and here is my function but it doesn't work it adds "undefined" is the list

```
function add_basket(that) {
    $(".basket").append("<li>"+that+"</li>");
}
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: use `var text = $(that).child('p').innerHTML;` inside the `add_basket` function before appending the text - `$(".basket").append("<li>"+text+"</li>");` Not much familiar with jquery

Comment: @RohitKumar That will not work.

Comment: where is the error? should use `children` instead of `child`? OHH I got it, I need to use `.html()` instead of `innerHTML`, right??

Comment: Right. After implementing those changes it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You make your request with handler jQuery
JS

```
$(".menu-item").click(function(){
   $(".basket").append("<li>"+$(this).children("p").text()+"</li>");
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="menu-item burger"> <img  src="img\McDo\bigmac.png"> <p>Big Mac</p> </div>
  <div class="menu-item burger"> <img  src="img\McDo\doubleqp.png"> <p>Double Quarter Pounder</p> </div>
```

Here you can test it in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwL8rdkx/1/)

Comment: perfect answer, here is the jsfiddle with very similar approach: https://jsfiddle.net/cwL8rdkx/1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the text

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-item burger">  
 <p class="item-name">Big Mac</p> 
</div>
<div class="menu-item burger"> 
 <p class="item-name">Double Quarter Pounder</p> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".item-name").click(function add_basket(that) {
    $(".basket").append("<li>"+that.target.innerHTML+"</li>");
});
```

The reason that your code didn't work is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/2713198).

> Never use .onclick(), or similar attributes from a userscript! (It's
>   also poor practice in a regular web page).
>
> The reason is that userscripts operate in a sandbox ("isolated
>   world"), and onclick operates in the target-page scope and cannot see
>   any functions your script creates.
>
> Always use addEventListener()Doc (or an equivalent library function,
>   like jQuery .on()).

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/a801ax32/)

Answer (score 0):

This will target the element it gets passed, in this example you're passing in "this" as "that" we then execute .find on "that" to located an p tag child elements and then .text to return the text contents from the child.

```
function add_basket(that) {
    $(".basket").append("<li>"+jQuery(that).find('p').text()+"</li>");
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain why this solves the problem?