# Adding a context menu attribute to the body element?

Tags: javascript, firefox, contextmenu, greasemonkey

I'm developing a userscript and one of its functions should be available thru an additional menu item in the native browser context menu.

So, firstly, I'm inserting into body of the page:

```
<menu type="context" id="mymenu">
    <menuitem label="My Fancy Something"></menuitem>
</menu>
```

Then comes the attempt to use it, at the body element:

```
document.body.contextMenu = document.querySelector('#mymenu');
```

or

```
document.body.contextMenu = 'mymenu';
```

Either way, it fails.

```
console.log(document.body.contextMenu); // returns null
```

But, when I get to Firefox DOM inspector, and put that attribute into the body tag by hand, it actually works, and makes new context menu element appear in the document.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to set `.contextMenu` for pretty much the same reason you should [avoid things like `.onclick()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/331508).  You will have scope and sandbox problems with that approach.

Set the `contextmenu` *attribute*, not the DOM property.

Here is **a complete working Greasemonkey script** that shows how to add a context menu:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Create and wire-in a sample context menu
// @match    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var myMenu  = $( `
    <menu type="context" id="myFirstContextMenu">
        <menuitem data-bg-color="pink"  label="Set background to pink."></menuitem>
        <menuitem data-bg-color="lime"  label="Set background to lime."></menuitem>
        <menuitem data-bg-color="reset" label="Reset background color."></menuitem>
    </menu>
` ).appendTo ("body");

$("body").attr ("contextmenu", 'myFirstContextMenu');

myMenu.on ("click", "menuitem", function (zEvent) {
    var targBgColor = $(this).data ("bgColor")  ||  "ERROR";

    switch (targBgColor) {
        case "pink":
        case "lime":
            $("body").css ("background-color", targBgColor);
            break;
        case "reset":
            $("body").css ("background-color", "");
            break;
        default:
            alert ('<menuitem> "' + targBgColor + '" not wired-in correctly.');
            break;
    }
} );
```

---

**Note:** This kind of `<menu>` seems to [only be supported by Firefox at the moment](http://caniuse.com/#feat=menu).

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Looks like the way to do it with vanilla js would be document.body.setAttribute('contextMenu','myMenu')

Comment: You're welcome and, yes, `setAttribute()` is the bare-bones JS way.

Comment: This seems to be broken. I'm not sure when exactly is happened, but it is not working any more with 85.0.2.

Comment: Yes `menu` is no longer supported from Firefox 85+ see https://caniuse.com/menu and https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2730