# Passing content from <textarea> to api controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I'm trying to pass content from a form (in a modal) to an api_controller. But I can't get the text out of my `<textarea>`... even with a simple **alert**

//Simple HTML-BOOTSTRAP form

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal65resp">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>New File</h4>
        </div>

        <!-- modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="newfileform" class="form-horizontal">

                <!-- filename -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filename" class="col-sm-2 control-label">FileName:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input name="filename" type="text" class="form-control" id="filename" placeholder="FileName">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- TxtArea -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtarea1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea type="text" name="txtarea1" id="txtarea1"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- apath -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="apath" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Absolute Path:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input name="savepath" type="text" class="form-control" id="savepath" placeholder="Absolute Path" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>


        <!-- modal-footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <div class="pull-left">
                <div id="info"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                <a class="btn btn-success " onclick="SaveFile()">Save File</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the script I'm trying to get working an a textarea, with CKEditor in use.

//script

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('txtarea1');
</script>
<script>
    function SaveFile()
    {
        var path = $('#savepath').val()
        var filename = $('#filename').val()
        var content = $('#txtarea1').val()

        alert(content);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/5074858 . This will help as it shows what is wrong with your code. And here is the working fiddle for your code.   https://jsfiddle.net/e6db4L3u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your CKEDITOR instance using `CKEDITOR.instances.txtarea1` and get the HTML using `getData`:

`CKEDITOR.instances.txtarea1.getData();`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Andrés