# Reversing User-Input String

Tags: javascript

Been banging my head on this. I'm trying to take user-input via form and print out their sentence backwards. It's not working and I'm not sure exactly why.

I used some code from [here](http://sstut.com/javascript/reverse-words-order-in-sentences.php) for the reverse string function.

I tried lots of different string reverse functions but most of them were too complicated to understand, so fairly beginner here. :) Any help would be truly appreciated.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var sentence, text;
    sentence = document.getElementById("numb")
    sentence = sentence.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, " " )
    sentence = sentence.replace( /\s+/g, " " );
    
    var words = sentence.split(" ");a
        words = words.reverse();
        sentence = words.join(" ");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p >Spell a sentence backwards.</p>
    <input id="numb">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dscpebo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple one-liner to reverse your string:

```js
var forward = "Forward sentence";

var backward = forward.split("").reverse().join("");

console.log(backward);
```

Split the string into an array of its characters, reverse the array and then join it back up again into a string. Got the idea from [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript-in-3-different-ways-75e4763c68cb).

If you just want to reverse the order of the words in the sentence (not the characters themselves) then simply `.split()` and `.join()` with a space as follows:

```js
var forward = "Forward sentence";

var backward = forward.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");

console.log(backward);
```

---

I've put this all together in your original example below. One modification is using an event listener rather than specifying the function in `onclick` which can sometimes create problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick).

```js
function reverseText() {
    var forward = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    var backward = forward.split("").reverse().join("");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = backward;
}

document.getElementById("btnsubmit").addEventListener("click", reverseText);
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Spell a sentence backwards.</p>
  <input id="numb">
  <button id="btnsubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of your comment. I'm curious how do I have the answer posted to a <p>. What is it that I'm missing? Here's what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/aw5tk1o3/

Comment: @ChrisMFerguson I've edited my answer to include the relevant content. Let me know if it still needs more clarification.

Comment: Hi, quick question, I was bringing your code into my editor and somehow it didn't work. It works in the code snippet but I couldn't get it to work. It works in JSFiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/j4dx36o1/ (this all my code that I have, not sure what's not working)

Comment: @ChrisMFerguson did you get an error? What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I should've been more specific, when I brought your code in, pressing the button didn't return anything. Just nothing was returned upon submit. I don't know if it's the "addeventlistener" method, but something isn't working.

Comment: @ChrisMFerguson I'd recommend you open a new question regarding this new problem. Unfortunately there isn't much I can do without seeing the broader context of where this code is being applied. Everything works in the JSFiddle and that's all I can work with as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a job for regex. Just loop backwards over the string and create a new string from it, character by character.

```js
var forward = 'this string is forward';

// create an empty string to fill with characters
var backward = '';

// loop backwards over forward
for (var i = forward.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  backward += forward[i];
}

console.log(backward);
```

Also, you need to get the text value from your `sentence` element.

```
var forward = sentence.value;
```

Comment: Thank you and how can you simply reverse the sentence, not the words themselves like: I like dogs > dogs like I

Comment: You would do the same thing but instead of iterating over a string, you'd iterate over an array and `.push()` items onto a new array.

Comment: You could also just use the array `.reverse()` method. However, this will reverse the original array, it won't return a new reversed array.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sentence` objects is an HTMLElement, not a javascript string, so you can't call string methods on it. I think you meant something more like

```
var sentence = document.getElementById("numb")

if (sentence) {
    //get the value of the Input element if it exists
    var sentenceText = sentence.value

    //...the rest of your code would go in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment in the code for the fix.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var sentence; //text is not used
    sentence = document.getElementById("numb").value; 
    //Need to get the actual value, not just the DOM
    sentence = sentence.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, " " )
    sentence = sentence.replace( /\s+/g, " " );
    var words = sentence.split(" ");
        words = words.reverse();
        sentence = words.join(" ");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sentence;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p >Spell a sentence backwards.</p>
    <input id="numb">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the *value* of the *input* box by using `document.getElementById('numb').value` and reverse this using the `#reverse()` method for arrays:

```
value.split('').reverse().join('')
```

See demo below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sentence = document.getElementById("numb").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sentence.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Spell a sentence backwards.</p>
  <input id="numb">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```