# JavaScript -- function does not get called

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, dom

I'd like to make a list about facts. When I click on the button the first fact should be replaced by the second and so on. But it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
var facts = ['1. ', '2. ', '3. ', '4. '];

var print = document.getElementById('myfacts');
print.innerHTML = facts[0];

var i = 1;

function go() {
  'use strict';
  print.innerHTML = facts[i];
  i = (i + 1) % (facts.length);
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<section id="fakten">
  <div class="facts">
    <h1>My 4 facts</h1>
    <script src="facts.js"></script>  
    <p id="myfacts" class="myfacts"></p>
    <a id="click" href="index.html" onclick="go();">Next</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

But it doesn't work. Could you help me?

Comment: It’s a dupe of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're looking for an element before it's created. Change the order:

```
<p id="myfacts" class="myfacts"></p>
<script src="facts.js"></script>
```

Another option is to use (some changes will be needed):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // you code
}
```

Beyond that you need to change from `href="index.html"` to `href="#"`, or prevent default behavior.

Comment: Changing the order works as same as it was before. The problem was the href="index.html".

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="facts.js"></script>
```

U are mising a `=` sign.

Also change `href="index.html"` to `href="#"`.

```js
var facts = ["1. ", "2. ", "3. ", "4. "];

    var i = 1;
    var print = document.getElementById('myfacts');

    print.innerHTML = facts[0];

    function go() {
        "use strict";
        print.innerHTML = facts[i];
        i = (i + 1) % (facts.length);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="fakten">
    <div class="facts">
        <h1>My 4 facts</h1>
        <script src="facts.js"></script>  
        <p id="myfacts" class="myfacts"></p>
        <a id="click" href="#" onclick="go();">Next</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: no thats not the problem, its only a mistake in the question

Comment: Why do you have 2 `href` in your anchor tag?

Comment: @HassanImam Thanks for pointing it. Just updated. Anyways that had nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: @Flowen i believe pointing `href` to "#" is what made the answer correct, as @Mike mentioned missing "=" was a typo

Comment: I think it is accidentally working here as the code snippet include the js in the end of body. And the mentioned js is not even being referenced.

Comment: The reason is that userscripts operate in a sandbox ("isolated world"), and onclick operates in the target-page scope and cannot see any functions your script creates.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of `href="index.html"`, instead use `href="#"`

```js
var facts = ["1. ", "2. ", "3. ", "4. "];

    var i = 1;
    var print = document.getElementById('myfacts');

    print.innerHTML = facts[0];

    function go() {
        "use strict";
        print.innerHTML = facts[i];
        i = (i + 1) % (facts.length);
    }
```

```html
<section id="fakten">
    <div class="facts">
        <h1>My 4 facts</h1>
        <script src="facts.js"></script>  
        <p id="myfacts" class="myfacts"></p>
        <a id="click" href="#" onclick="go();">Next</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem, page stays the same since this is probably his index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you open a console, does it say go is not defined? Define it like so:

```
go = function() {
        print.innerHTML = facts[i];
        i = (i + 1) % (facts.length); 
}
```

Now it's bound globally and working.

```js
var facts = ["1. ", "2. ", "3. ", "4. "];

    var i = 1;
    var print = document.getElementById('myfacts');

    print.innerHTML = facts[0];

    go = function() {
        "use strict";
        print.innerHTML = facts[i];
        i = (i + 1) % (facts.length);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="fakten">
    <div class="facts">
        <h1>My 4 facts</h1>
        <script src="facts.js"></script>  
        <p id="myfacts" class="myfacts"></p>
        <a id="click" href="#" onclick="go();">Next</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Polluting the global namespace like this is terrible practice—don't do that. This is for test purposes.

The root of the problem is explained in the answers to this question: [Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick)

There is an entire list of bad stuff happening in this code. You might consider the following:

1. Why href to index.html?
2. Why use the link at all? Use html5 button for that.
3. Why is use strict in the function? (I don't see a reason why.)

Comment: thank you @Cody Gray I just learned more about how to work with SO to produce better-styled answers!

Comment: Yeah, Stack Snippets are basically like our own version of JSFiddle, with the advantage that they work *directly* in the post (and the links never go down!). You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to execute by wrapping the javascript in a callback for the `DOMContentLoaded` listener and making a few changes. This way the DOM is full loaded before the script executes. It ensures that the `#myfacts` and `#click` elements are accessible before the script runs. I also changed the `<a>` into a `<button>` to avoid being redirected to `index.html` and moved the `onclick` registration into the script itself.

Markup:

```
<section id="fakten">
    <div class="facts">
        <h1>My 4 facts</h1>
        <script src="./js.js"></script>  
        <p id="myfacts" class="myfacts"></p>
        <button id="click">Next</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Javscript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var facts = ["1. ", "2. ", "3. ", "4. "];
    var i = 1;

    var print = document.getElementById('myfacts');
    var button = document.getElementById('click');

    button.onclick = function () {
      "use strict";
      print.innerHTML = facts[i];
      i = (i + 1) % (facts.length);
    }

    print.innerHTML = facts[0];
});
```