# Changing background image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, getelementsbyclassname

I have been trying to create a slideshow on one of the web pages I've been creating. I have created a div with a unique class name that is targeted in order to change the background image using JavaScript. So far, I have been able to do the following:

1. Capture the div where I want to change the background image by using the querySelector
2. Attempted to change the background image of said div using JavaScript

I have been debugging this function using DevTools, yet I cannot figure out why the image won't change. Any idea what is happening here? I have included snippets of the code below. Thank you.

HTML

```
<div class="content-one-right">
  <div class="inner-content-one-right">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <a class="prev" onclick="transitionSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="transitionSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-one-right {
  grid-column: col-start 7 / span 6;
  height: 60vh;
}

.inner-content-one-right {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}

.slideshow-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url('../images/home-slideshow/home1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

JavaScript

```
var slideshowIndex = 0;

function transitionSlides(n) {

  var images = ["home1", "home2", "home3", "home4", "home5", "home6"];
  slideshowIndex += n;

  if(slideshowIndex < 0) {
    slideshowIndex = images.length-1;
  }
  else if (slideshowIndex >= images.length) {
    slideshowIndex = 0;
  }

  var getContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-container')[0];
  var imageToChange = "url('../images/home-slideshow/" + images[slideshowIndex] + ".jpg')";

  getContainer.style.backgroundImage = imageToChange;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you are trying to change the background image.  The first time you set it, you are setting it in the stylesheet.  You are using a CSS property there.

Later, you try to change it using the `.style` property of the element.  These aren't the same thing.  From [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

> The style property is not useful for completely learning about the
>   styles applied on the element, since it represents only the CSS
>   declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those
>   that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the
>    section, or external style sheets.

To clarify, try this in your console on this very page: `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[3].style`

This grabs the blue button at the bottom of the page that says "Post Your Answer".  It's pretty clearly got a blue background that is set in the CSS.  But that CSSDeclaration object in your console has only *empty* values.  That's because it only reflects the *inline* styles, not the styles you applied with CSS.

Fun, right?  With that knowledge, I think you can choose one way or the other to make your slideshow happen the way you expect.  It's probably easiest to not use background image at all, though.  I think it's conventional to have an `img` tag there and use javascript to set the `src` attribute.

Comment: Interesting. That would explain it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the same issue as seen [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick). There's good information provided there too. When running your code in JSFiddle, it just throws the following exception: `transitionSlides is not defined.` Remove the onclick handler and use `addEventListener()` instead. It would be best to use ID's for your prev and next buttons but this will work:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-one-right">
    <div class="inner-content-one-right">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var slideshowIndex = 0;

document.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    transitionSlides(-1);
}, false);
document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    transitionSlides(1);
}, false);

function transitionSlides(n) {

    var images = ["home1", "home2", "home3", "home4", "home5", "home6"];
    slideshowIndex += n;

    if(slideshowIndex < 0) {
        slideshowIndex = images.length-1;
    }
    else if (slideshowIndex >= images.length) {
        slideshowIndex = 0;
    }

    var getContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-container')[0];
    var imageToChange = "url('../images/home-slideshow/" + images[slideshowIndex] + ".jpg')";

    getContainer.style.backgroundImage = imageToChange;

}
```