# Problems with javascript event handler

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

I'm hoping this doesn't get marked as "duplicate", because I have reviewed several threads and followed the advice I found.  I know I'm missing something simple, and need other eyes on this.  I'm a newbie, so please bear with me.  I am testing a simple button element that I have a click event handler on, but it is not working.  It works inline with "onclick", but I am trying to avoid that.  The simple html:

```
<div>
    <button id='handler'>Event</button>
</div>
<div id='stringText'>
    <h4>Some Description</h4>
    <p>
        Some more information
    </p>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("handler").addEventListener("click", display, true);
    function display() {

        if (document.getElementById("stringText").style.display === "block") {
            document.getElementById("stringText").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("stringText").style.display = "block";
        }

    };

</script>
```

I have the css that initially sets the "stringText" display as "none".  I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Mixing CSS and the `style` prop is funny business.  Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49289840/3662110

Comment: This was a good read, and makes sense.  I will correct the practice going forward, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please allow some delay to load the pages using `window.onload` events

```html
<div>
    <button id='handler'>Event</button>
</div>
<div id='stringText'>
    <h4>Some Description</h4>
    <p>
        Some more information
    </p>
</div>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById("handler").addEventListener("click", display, true);
};
   
    function display() {

        if (document.getElementById("stringText").style.display === "block") {
            document.getElementById("stringText").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("stringText").style.display = "block";
        }

    };

</script>
```

Comment: Updated with event, please check.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you.  @Ele, this solution was helpful as well.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

- Probably your problem is related to the execution of that script while the document is being loaded.
- Add this condition `stringText.style.display === ""` to show/hide the elements correctly.

An alternative is using the event **[`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  document.getElementById("handler").addEventListener("click", display, true);

  function display() {
    var stringText = document.getElementById("stringText");
    if (stringText.style.display === "block" || stringText.style.display === "") {
      stringText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      stringText.style.display = "block";
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id='handler'>Event</button>
</div>
<div id='stringText'>
  <h4>Some Description</h4>
  <p>
    Some more information
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure and set the initial display property to block it works fine. As an alternative, you could also try using `jQuery`, as I have in the snippet.

```js
//with jquery

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#handler').on('click', function() {
    $('#stringText').toggleClass('hide');
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id='handler'>Event</button>
</div>
<div id='stringText'>
  <h4>Some Description</h4>
  <p>
    Some more information
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a js event to capture when the DOM is loaded.  jQuery is unnecessary.