# WordPress - Onclick functions not working in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am creating a sliding sidebar menu for my WordPress site using only HTML/CSS/JavaScript. This is from a tutorial from YouTube and followed everything exactly. The issue is that when I click on the buttons, the error reads "Uncaught ReferenceError: openSlideMenu is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick". I get the same error for the other button. See code below.

HTML (blog.php)

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="side-menu">
        <span class="open-slide">
            <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
               <svg width="30" height="30">
                <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
                <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
                <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
               </svg> 

            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <a  href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
        <?php get_sidebar() ?>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    function openSlideMenu() {
        document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
    }

      function closeSlideMenu() {
        document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';

    }

});

</script>
```

CSS

```
.side-nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: 0.9;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;

}

.side-nav a {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:22px;
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.side-nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 22px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

The tutorial seemed easy and simple, it should have worked without issues. I wonder could it be something WordPress related? I did all I could.

Comment: try put your javascript in `<head></head>` tag

Comment: @Rendi No luck.

Comment: Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/4378314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, why don't you utilize it completely?

For more information on what could be the issue, I suggest you take a look at [MarsAndBlack's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354930/wordpress-onclick-functions-not-working-in-a-tag#comment85710528_49354930)

Meanwhile, I made some changes to your code to make use of jQuery fully.

Here I have added ids to both buttons. *(Not necessary, but used for easy detection).*

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="side-menu">
        <span class="open-slide">
            <a href="#" id="openmenu">
               <svg width="30" height="30">
                <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
                <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
                <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
               </svg> 

            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <a  href="#" class="btn-close" id="closemenu">&times;</a>

</div>
```

Also changed JS to use jQuery for click function instead of vanilla JS,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery('#openmenu').click(function() {
             jQuery('#side-menu').css('width','250px');

   });

   jQuery('#closemenu').click(function() {
             jQuery('#side-menu').css('width','0px');

   });
});
```

Here is a working [example](https://jsbin.com/zireganepe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: It worked! Why didn't I think of this? I knew I could use the .click() method but not sure how could I do it with the .style method? I see you used the .css() method without the .getDocumentById. I need to brush up my jQuery skills some more. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help