# javascript functions nor working/called from index file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have tow file first is index.php and the another is user.js 
I included user.js into index.php file . 
but the scripts functions not working from external file so if I put this functions directly in index.php it working perfectly but not working when putting them in external file

```
<script src="js/user.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is function which is into `users.js`.

```
function deletemessage(id) {

    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'Save.php?id=delete_msg&msg_id=' + id,

        beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({
                'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c'
            }, 300);
        },
        success: function(data) { //alert(data);
            $('#message_ha').html(data);
            parent.slideUp(300, function() {
                parent.remove();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your function? Have you included jQuery? Does the console show any errors? You say you have two files (`index.php` and `user.js`), yet your AJAX request is pointing to `Save.php`, what is in that file?

Comment: Can you add the error you get? Maybe you just gave an incorrect path?

Comment: try this: `src="/js/user.js"`

Comment: I don't get any error

Comment: not working so sorry

Comment: @Maj.jad my comment above should help you find a potential issue, have you tried the above?

Comment: @Script47  I included jquery in index.php file , save.php is file which is used to save records into database .all this code working  nice when I put code into index.php but not working at all when move script to external file

Comment: Most probably, you have a wrong path indicated in path. You can check you devtools network section to check if your js file is correctly loaded

Comment: what error does your browser console report when you click the button? Inspect the html of button, switch to the necessary tab and look for the error that is being generated from pushing the button. [For example in Chrome.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: deletemessage is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: Could be that it's looking for `Save.php` in the same directory as your `users.js` file. Try adding `/` before `Save.php`

Comment: no save.php and index.php in same folder but user.js in js folder

Comment: yes, in your js file you have `url :'Save.php...'` change it to `url:'/Save.php..'`

Comment: no it not working , I deleted all code into function and just adding alert('hello') but it still not working

Comment: update the question showing the snippet of html from index.php with the button

Comment: I don't know but I changed created new  javascript and placed the js code into this new js file , and included it in to index.php  and worked fine

Comment: I have found similar questions to this issue. [Do no use onclick but use the object id with an event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick/17378538). Here is it for JS but there is a similar practice for jQuery

Comment: I was also going to mention that it might be a browser caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but I changed created new  javascript and placed the js code into this new js file , and included it in to index.php  and worked fine

Answer (score -2):

Can you drag User.js file from js folder And drop in Index.php .