# Sign out from my account in a website after login with google plus

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sign out from my website after login using google plus
this is my script for signout

```
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');           
    });
}
```

this is signout button

```
<li id="google_plus" style=""><a href="#" onclick="signOut()">Logouts</a></li>
```

but when i try to sign out this error will show

> Uncaught ReferenceError: signOut is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM684 home:269)

Comment: you may like this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick/17378538?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is telling you that your `signOut()` function can't be found.

Try reformatting your code, as follows, and remove `onclick="signOut()"` from your HTML - it should stop that error from showing.

I notice you've tagged the question with jQuery - so I assume you're using it. You could try this:

```js
$('#google_plus_a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="google_plus" style=""><a href="#" id="google_plus_a">Logouts</a></li>
```

Comment: The error you're getting is telling you that your ```signOut()``` function can't be found. If you use the code example I have given in your code, and remove ```onclick="signOut()"``` from your HTML - it should stop that error from showing.

Comment: yes i remove onclick="signout()" from html ,but nothing happen console message not show.if i remove signout() then what to write in line auth2.signOut().then(function ()  in place of signOut().

Comment: Have you refactored your code, so it looks as mine does in the example above?

Comment: Sounds like jQuery isn't targeting your element. See my updated example (HTML and Javascript).