# Extjs Function Not Found Issue

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have written a simple ExtJS grid with a column `renderer` that returns an HTML hyperlink for an `onclick` to call a simple JavaScript function.

Unfortunately, when I click it shows function undefined in the browser console. Any Help is Appreciated.

```
function myALert() {
    alert("yo");
}

function columnRenderer(val) {
    return '<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="myALert()">View</a>'
}
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        renderer: columnRenderer
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Is that function global.By global I mean that when your page loads is that function initialized.If its global then you can check in this way: just type name of function in browser console & there function gets displayed.If function is not initialized then it prints undefined.
So check this and reply.

Comment: console shows myALert is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
Found this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick
Can someone help me in how this can be incorporated in my situation?

Answer (score 1):

The use of global functions in this case where it will be used in only one column is not recommended.

I suggest using `Action Column`, which has the `handler` property that performs a function on the click. See this documentation [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.grid.column.Action.html).

If it is necessary to use a link (tag a), I suggest using `Template Column`, where you can create the template you prefer using HTML markup and other resources. See this documentation [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.grid.column.Template.html).

Take a look in this forked [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2m22) from [Akrion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155819/akrion). There is one grid with Action Column and another with Template Column.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Lisa',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224'
            }, {
                name: 'Bart',
                email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1234'
            }, {
                name: 'Homer',
                email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1244'
            }, {
                name: 'Marge',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1254'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons (Grid with Action Column)',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                align: 'center',
                icon: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/eye.png',
                getTip: function(value) {
                    return value;
                },
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {
                    alert("Yo! " + record.get('phone'));
                }
            }],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons (Grid with Template Column)',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                align: 'center',
                tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<a href="{[this.myAlert(values)]}">{phone}</a>',
                    {
                        myAlert: function(values){
                           return "javascript:alert('Yo! "+values.phone+"')";
                        }
                    }
                )
            }],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a much better way to go.

Comment: yeah this is the best thing I guess. Only one more requirement that I have is that the button should look like a hyperlink. Is that possible?

Comment: You can do it through css.