# Scroll down to specific div when the user clicks the button

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want the screen to scroll down to the div. This div has an ID of 'weather-data'

I have tried the following;

```
document.getElementById('weather-data').scrollIntoView();
```

I have also tried using anchor tags this did not seem to work

The button which the user will click:

```
<button id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
                    Submit
                </button>
```

The function that runs when the button is clicked:

```
function myFunction(){
    cityName();

    getData();

    clear();

    document.getElementById('weather-data').scrollIntoView();
}
```

This is the div I want the screen to scroll to:

```
<div id="weather-data">

</div>
```

Comment: Use addEventListener instead, here is a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/eavgp0bh/1/

Comment: @DanielDoblado While I agree that `.addEventListener()` is the modern and better approach, it has nothing to do with this code working or not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree too, I was trying to find a solution just using onclick, most likely this won"t work because quoting this issue `onclick operates in the target-page scope and cannot see any functions your script creates` More information here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538/2498992 I just wanted to provide a working solution in the case using my approach is not a problem for the user.

Comment: @DanielDoblado That post has nothing to do with this issue. That post specifically deals with the use of inline event attributes in conjunction with element creation using `innerHTML` and `outerHTML`. The whole thing about `onclick` not being able to see any functions your script creates is not a true statement in and of itself. The OPs code works as is, it is the calling of the other functions that is stopping it.

Answer (score 2):

use the anchor tag to link the the div

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

div{
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='a'>a</div>
    <div id='b'>b</div>
    <div id='c'>c</div>
    <div id='d'>d</div>
    <div id='e'>e</div>
    <button><a href='#c'>go to c</a></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue I had to write an if statement to check if there was any text in the h1 element.

```
if(weatherMain != null){

                document.getElementById('icon').scrollIntoView();
                document.getElementById('weather-main').scrollIntoView();

            }
```