# How to sanitize the html file which having both html tags and java script functions in an angular application

Tags: jquery, angular

I try to get bind html file which having both html and java script (JQuery) function into my angular application.

This is how I bind my html file into component html.

```
<div [innerHTML]="currentDetailEntry?.content | sanitizeHtml"></div>
```

I created the @pipe to fulfil this task.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

 constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {  }

  transform(v: string, type: string): safeHTML {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v); 
  }
}
```

So, when I click button which has onClick event is not working.

Error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: soundPlay is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick*

This is how html file content looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTDXHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="height:100%; border-right: 14px solid #FEE0A0; border-left: 14px solid #FEE0A0; border-bottom: 14px solid #FEE0A0" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="Fascia" valign="top" align="left">Embeded Text</td>
                    <td class="Face" valign="top" align="right">PCL</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td valign="top" height="100%"> 
                        <div class="Entry"> 
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td valign="baseline">
                                        <img src="se/images/flag_lang2_22_16.gif" alt="">&nbsp;
                                        <span class="Hword"><span class="tt">aardwolf</span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="Phon">/&#712;&#593;&#720;dw&#650;lf</span>
                                        <span class="Gramm">Am</span> 
                                        <span class="Phon">&#712;&#593;&#720;rdw&#650;lf/</span>
                                        <script> //====================================================================== var soundEmbed = null; var Path = "snd/se/" var Ext = ".mp3" var Mime = "audio/mpeg" var noDisplay = "height:0;width:0" //====================================================================== function soundPlay(which) { which = Path + which + Ext // alert("Play sound " + which); if (!soundEmbed) { soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed"); soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", which); soundEmbed.setAttribute("style", noDisplay); soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true); soundEmbed.setAttribute("type", Mime); } else { document.body.removeChild(soundEmbed); soundEmbed.removed = true; soundEmbed = null; soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed"); soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", which); soundEmbed.setAttribute("style", noDisplay); soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true); soundEmbed.setAttribute("type", Mime); } soundEmbed.removed = false; document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed); } //====================================================================== </script>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <a onClick="soundPlay('00/00013'); return false" href="#" class="button">
                                        <img src="se/images/sound_play_button.gif" name="img" onmouseover="document.img.src='se/images/sound_play_hover.gif'" onmouseout="document.img.src='se/images/sound_play_button.gif'" alt="" title=" Play " border=""></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td valign="top"> 
                                        <div class="Part"> 
                                            <span class="Num2"></span> 
                                            <span class="HwGramm" title=" sostantivo ">n.</span>
                                            <p class="trans"> 
                                                <span class="Num"></span>
                                                (<span class="Cat" title=" zoologia ">Zool</span>)
                                                <span class="Trad"><span class="tt">protele</span></span> 
                                                <span class="Gramm">m.</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </div>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td height="53"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="copy">Copyright &copy; </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share how the "currentDetailEntry?.content" looks like?

Comment: I edited my question. you can see now.

Comment: I believes this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick will helps you. Never use the onClick from userscript.

Answer (score 0):

being in Angular context you should use:

```
(click)="..."
```

instead

```
onClick="..."
```

Then i've seen in your html that there is 2 occurrences of double closed `<span>` tag, maybe this can be part of the problem too.