# Dynamic content on page is not showing

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am trying to generate dynamic content on page with the onclick event of js but there is error in console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

html

```
{% load static %}
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
        // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "{{ Malegender }}";
      }
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
<h1>Gender</h1>
      <hr>
      <h5>{{ mygender.as_p }}</h5>
      <h1 id="demo">Hello</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <button type="submit" name="gender_submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction()">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

views.py

```
def Gender(request):
    gender_selection = GenderForm()
    male_detail = MaleForm()
    Male = False
    print("Value of male",Male)
    if 'gender_submit' in request.POST:
        male_detail = MaleForm(data=request.POST)
        Male = True
        print("Value of male d",Male)

    print("Value of male a",Male)
    return render(request, 'Gender.html',{"mygender":gender_selection,"Malegender":male_detail})
```

forms.py

```
class MaleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GenderModel
        fields = ('genderMale','genderMale1','genderMale2','genderMale3','genderMale4')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
# Create your models here.

class GenderModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    gender_choice=(('Male','Male'),('Female','Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=gender_choice,null=True,)
    genderMale = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genderMale1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genderMale2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genderMale3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genderMale4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        GenderModel.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.gendermodel.save()
```

when I click on button the error on the console is showing. I am trying to display that content when the user clicks on the button

Comment: Is the error in your python console, or is it in your browser?  Also, can you post the full error with the traceback?

Comment: the error is in the browser's console

Comment: (index):43 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: <button type="submit" name="gender_submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction()">Confirm</button>
        
error is in above line according to console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick) question suggests *never* using the `onclick` attribute.  Instead you can try using an event listener like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="gender_submit" class="btn btn-success"
id="gender_submit_button">Confirm</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "{{ Malegender }}";
}

document.getElementById('gender_submit_button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
</script>
```

Also, make sure that your script is placed *after* the button and demo.