# How to call javascript functions inside a <script type="module"> from HTML element events?

Tags: javascript, import, scope

I have a simple HTML page, which is importing a JS module as follows:

```
.. snip
<button onclick="btnClick()">Go!</button>

<script type="module">
import { func1 } from './utils.js'

function btnClick() {
   func1()
}
</script>
```

Clicking the button produces an error: btnClick() is not defined.

Why is this happening?  How to bring these functions back into correct scope?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick)

Answer (score 7):

The javascript execution stack has own scope, so, simple and easy solution is, you can assign to window scope your accessible functions like below;

```
<button onclick="btnClick()">Go!</button>

<script type="module">
    import { func1 } from './utils.js'

    function btnClick() {
      func1()
    }

    // variable function
    window.btnClick = btnClick;

    // or anonymous function
    window.btnClick = function(youCanSetParams){
      func1()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you have multiple functions, do something like  `window._myFns = { btnClick, onLoad }`

Answer (score 1):

Variable from "module" are not accessible from outside so use type="text/javascript" as

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function btnClick() {
   console.log('here')
}
</script>
<button onclick="btnClick()">Go!</button>
```

Comment: This answer provides a workaround, but not the actual answer to what the OP asked. Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: You can only use import and export statements inside modules, not regular scripts -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 1):

when the script is with module type it can only listen to events and you can not call to function from the html ,
so you can add an EventListener to the click event , check the id of the target element that call dispatch the event and then call to the function:

```
<script type="module">
    import { func1 } from './utils.js'
    window.addEventListener('click' , e=> {
        switch(e.target.id){
           case 'btnGo':
             btnClick();
             break;
        }
    })
    function btnClick() {
       func1()
    }
</script>

<html>
    <button id="btnGo">Go!</button>
</html>
```