# Strange append issue

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="formElement" id="debtors">
    <label> Debtors</label>
    <input type="text" name="debtors">
    <button id="btnClicker" onclick="test()">Append list items</button>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
test= function(){
    var clicked = 0;
    $("#btnClicker").click(function(){
        clicked++;
        $("#debtors").append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test"+clicked+"\" value=\"test\" />");
      });                       
};
```

[JS fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gnJ5V/1/)

The problem is that when the function is executed the input box is not shown at the 1st click and after the 2nd click there are 2 input boxes added and after few more clicks the boxes are duplicated for a strange reason. I tried almost everything that I found online, but it seems that I'm still new in jquery. I'm opretty sure that I'm missing something small. Do you have any fix ideas?

Comment: The HTML in your fiddle is different from the question. This makes the answers very confusing, since they refer to an `onclick` attribute that isn't in the question.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry.Just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also remove the `.click()` from your JS code

```
test = function () {
    var clicked = 0;
    clicked++;
    $("#debtors").append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test" + clicked + "\" value=\"test\" />");
}
```

or remove `onclick="test"` and keep you `.click()` script.

To know reason check [jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12627443/1671639).

Comment: @Slim I' glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `onclick` attribute from the button and everything should work fine like:

```
var clicked = 0;
$("#btnClicker").click(function () {
    clicked++;
    $("#debtors").append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test" + clicked + "\" value=\"test\" />");
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnJ5V/2/)

Your issue occurred since you had a onclick event nested inside another onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onclick()` from mark up, You were writing click inside click.

```
var clicked = 0;
$("#btnClicker").click(function(){
    clicked++;
    $("#debtors").append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test"+clicked+"\" value=\"test\" />");
  });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnJ5V/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Because your event handler **does not applies** until the user clicks at the button. The `onclick="test()"` on your code execute the function `test()` which later holds event handler.

#### You do not need a function on variable `test` just remove them.

```
var clicked = 0;
$("#btnClicker").click(function(){
    clicked++;
    $("#debtors").append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test"+clicked+"\" value=\"test\" />");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gnJ5V/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="formElement" id="debtors">
                <label> Debtors</label>
                <input type="text" name="debtors">
                <button id="btnClicker"">Append list items</button>
            </div>

</body>
```

And the script,

```
<script>

var clicked = 0;
$("#btnClicker").click(function(){
    clicked++;
    $("#debtors").append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"test"+clicked+"\" value=\"test\" />");
  });                       

</script>
```