# a tag onclick function call in each case

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, onclick

is it possible to call an onclick event in each cases of this code

```
  buildPager: function(slideIndex){
switch(slideIndex){
  case 0:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 1:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 2:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 3:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 4:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
}
}
```

because each cases are clickable so there must be a code for it, and that code is inside another code which is this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider1').bxSlider({
slideWidth: 5000,
minSlides: 1,
maxSlides: 1,
slideMargin: 10,
infiniteLoop: true,
hideControlOnEnd: false,
mode: 'horizontal',
useCSS: false,
easing: 'easeOutElastic',
speed: 2000,
buildPager: function(slideIndex){
switch(slideIndex){
  case 0:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 1:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 2:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 3:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
  case 4:
    return '<img src="images/mask.png">';
     }
   }
 });
 });
 </script>
```

it's a bxslider code.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

- bind click event using id's, e.g. `$("#image_1").click(function(){});`
- bind click event using a class selector, e.g. `$(".slider-image").click(function(){});`
- bind click event using the  tag itself, e.g. `$("img").click(function(){});`, but this will bind a click event to all images on the page, unless you surround them with a class-specfic container, in that case `$(".containerName img").click(function(){});`

Comment: Another option is delegation, which is probably a safer bet here, since we don't know what's going on: `$('.slider1').on('click', 'img', function(){});`  (assuming the images are appended to .slider1).

Comment: i mean is this code posible? <a href="" onClick="case0"></a><a href="" onClick="case1"></a> so far so on ... its what im trying to acheive because im gonna use it on a navigation (jquery) but the code with those cases is on a different jquery which is the bxslider

Comment: the cases are links which is slides to a content which maybe we can set it up on a tag link with an onclick ...

Comment: @CiprianPatrimonioDiolaJrII, binding events using onClick() is considered outdated and you should try to use more modern techniques for event registration.  See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick) for a good explanation on the topic.