# Using .click() rather than inline onclick

Tags: jquery, events

I have always went with the inline onclick approach as such:

```
<a href="#" id="do-something" onclick="doSomething(<?= $row['id'] ?>); return false;">
```

But I notice this isn't what the majority of websites do. They tend to do this:

```
<a href="#" id="do-something">

$("#do-something").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething();
    // --------^
})
```

The only problem is, how do I get the parameter that I supplied in example one so I can use it in example two? What's the correct process? Maybe add some hidden divs?

Comment: btw, that's a good read on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick

Comment: @Leon Thanks for the post. I ran across that post multiple times while a was searching for an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign that value to a custom data attribute, something like `data-row="<? php ... ?>"`. Now access it with: `$(this).data("row");`

Comment: Ah yes, I've seen that. I wasn't sure if that was the _"correct"_ way to do it. Is there anything I should be aware about before doing this?

Comment: Ehh... nothing out of the ordinary, `data-*` is just a custom attribute that will pass HTML validation, perfect for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use data attributes, like this:

```
<a href="#" id="do-something" data-row="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
```

And then this function:

```
$("#do-something").click(function(e) {
    var row = $(this).data('row');
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething(row);
});
```