# Javascript images slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I've just started learning javascript and Id like some help with a slideshow I'm trying to make. Here's the code. All it's supposed to do is cycle through 3 images when you click a button.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<script>
function Slideshow(){

        switch(x){
            default:
            document.getElementById("img").src="images/image2.jpg";
            var x=1;
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("img").src="images/image3.jpg";
            x++;
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("img").src="images/image1.jpg";
            x++;
            break;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="homepage_title">
    <h1>Slideshow</h1>
</div>

<div id="slideshow_wrapper">
    <div id="image">
        <img id="img" src="images/image1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="slideshow_button_right">
        <button type="button" onclick="Slideshow()">Next</button>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, what is the question?

Comment: Well it doesn't work at all. It seems that the variable doesn't persist after the button is click once. For example, when you click the button it switches to the second image, but when its clicked again, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `.onclick()`. It's poor practice in Javascript ([more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick/12627478#12627478)).

Use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener). Also, as you are just cycling through 3 different images, you really don't need a switch/case (which is also missing the `x` variable). Instead, you could just use an incrementing variable. So your code would look like this (rough code, can be improved):

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<script>

var x = 1;
function Slideshow(){
    document.getElementById("img").src="images/image"+x+".jpg";
    x++;
    if (x > 3)
        x = 1;
}

document.getElementById ("button-click").addEventListener ("click", Slideshow, false);

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="homepage_title">
    <h1>Slideshow</h1>
</div>

<div id="slideshow_wrapper">
    <div id="image">
        <img id="img" src="images/image1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="slideshow_button_right">
        <button id="button-click" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```