# Copying stored text in a table and then display it back into a textarea

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

How can I go about copying text (with the line breaks included) from my table and put it back into the textarea “newtext”

My existing coding doesn't seem to be working.

```
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

.box { width: 400px; height: 50px; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ta() {

    taValue = document.getElementById("ta").value

    taValue = taValue.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')

    document.getElementById("tatext").innerHTML = taValue
}

function text2area() {

    document.getElementById("newtext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tatext").innerHTML

}

</script>

</head>

<textarea class="box" id="ta" onkeyup="ta()"></textarea>

<table id="tatable"><tr><td><div id="tatext"></div></td></tr></table>

<br>

<input type="button" onclick="text2area()" value="move text">

<br><br>

<textarea class="box" id="newtext"></textarea>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the function `innerHTML`, grab the `value` of the text area you want to capture, and set the `value` of the new text area to this.  You are already using `value` for the variable `taValue`.  Also, it's [better practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick/12627478#12627478) to use `addEventListener` for your clicks and keyups.

```
function ta() {
    taValue = document.getElementById("ta").value
    taValue = taValue.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')
    document.getElementById("tatext").value = taValue;
}

function text2area() {
    taValue = document.getElementById("ta").value;
    document.getElementById("newtext").value = taValue;
}

document.getElementById("ta").addEventListener ("onkeyup", ta, false);
document.getElementById("move-text").addEventListener ("click", text2area, false);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tMJ84/1/

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` does not have an `innerHTML`. Notice how you grabbed the `value`? Set it the same way! It is like this because it is a form element.

```
document.getElementById("tatext").value = taValue; //semi-colons are just good practice
```

and here:

```
document.getElementById("newtext").value = document.getElementById("tatext").value;
```