# What is the best tag for onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote this code:

```
<div onclick="f()"></div>
```

But this code doesn't work on some systems, I think "onclick" may work with other tags properly, Is there anybody have same experience with this problem?

Comment: did you write function `f()` anywhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.click() vs onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Comment: doesn;t work on which systems?

Comment: <div id="idname" onclick="functionName('param')">. This is how it is done. But whats is your problem? which are the tags in which on click is not working. Share info.

Comment: do elaborate your problem

Comment: In the old days, `onclick` only worked on links (i.e., anchor elements `a`), and only on links with an `href` specified. It's been a long time since those days, so now you can safely use `onclick` on almost any displayed element not containing another HTML resource (because the HTML displayed in that resource would be given its own click handling abilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like use javascript mixed with HTML, when you have a large app debug would be messy, I prefer delegate an onClick event on this fashion:

```
<button id="my_button">Click me!</div>

<script>
    (function () {
        var btn = document.getElementById('my_button');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            alert('Click!');
        });
    }());
</script>
```

In the code before we are setting an event listener to the button which will invoke that callback function. I have used a button, but it is the same with a div. The live example: http://jsfiddle.net/TonyMtz/pT4nw/2/

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your onclick works fine.

If you have it on a div, you might have problems of it not actually having any size (often an empty div will have 100% width and 0px height, unless something's in it).

I'd suggest double checking that your div has size to it.

Here's a working jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/UmelibO/1/edit