# AJAX with jQuery, send variable to data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can I give jQuery a variable with the .ajax method?

Now I have something like this:
`<button onclick="sendQuery()">`

```
function sendQuery(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "action.php",
        async: false,
        data: {id: 560, 
               message: "Some message to you"  
    }
}
```

But is it possible to do like this way:
`<button onclick="sendQuery(560, 'Some message to you')">`

```
function sendQuery(myId, myMessage){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "action.php",
        async: false,
        data: {id: myId,
               message: myMessage  
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not a problem with that. The only thing I noticed is that in your function declaration you are inverting the order of the arguments. It should be `function sendQuery(myId, myMessage)`

Comment: you could add a `value` or `data-` attribute to the button with the message in it. then in your first `sendQuery()` function add `var message = $(this).val() // or $(this).data('attribute')` on the lines before the ajax call

Comment: Please don't use `async: false` if you can possibly help it. JavaScript executes in a single thread, so your synchronous code degrades the user's experience and even other scripts on the page. To answer your question: sure, that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the message to a `data-` attribute on the button and then use that within your `sendQuery()` function:

```
<button onclick="sendQuery()" data-mymessage="Some message to you">
```

then:

```
    function sendQuery(){
        var myMessage = $(this).data("mymessage");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "action.php",
            async: false,
            data: {id: 560, 
                   message: myMessage  
        }
    }
```

Really, you shouldn't be using the onclick attribute for the button anyway.. it is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick/12627478#12627478)

The ideal way to do it would be more like:

```
<button id="myButton" data-mymessage="Some message to you" data-myID="560">
```

then in the JS:

```
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var myMessage = $(this).data("mymessage");
        var myID = $(this).data("myID");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "action.php",
                    async: false,
                    data: {id: myID, 
                           message: myMessage  
                }
    });
```

The id can be replaced with a class instead if you want to use the same functionality from multiple buttons (re-use the code) just change the `#` in the JS to a `.` and use the `class=""` attribute on all required buttons.

The above requires jQuery, but it looks like you already have included that if your `$.ajax..` is working correctly..

Comment: When is it better to use my method and use yours? And why?

Comment: @Jake's way is [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). The HTML markup would define structure without behavior. The JavaScript code's job then would be to define behavior separately. Many would argue that this is a cleaner approach.

Comment: I added a slight improvement towards a better method. As mentioned, this is an unobtrusive method and can result in cleaner and more re usable code.