# RadioButton onclick event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a group of `RadioButton` which should have an `onclick` event.  This `onclick` event (`SecurityCheckedChanged`) will show/hide other dividers (filled `with` RadioButton) based on what `RadioButton` was clicked.

However, `SecurityCheckedChanged` doesn't seem to work.  I'm not sure if there is something I'm misunderstanding about `onclick` events when it comes to `RadioButton`.  Or if this `.is(':checked')` is incorrect?

JavaScript:

```
//this seems to fire off fine
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWEP').hide();
    $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWPA').hide();
}

//however this doesn't seem to work.
function SecurityCheckedChanged() {
    if ($("#<%= radWEP.ClientID %>").is(':checked')) {
        $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWEP').show();
        $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWPA').hide();
    }
    else if ($("#<%= radWPA.ClientID %>").is(':checked') || $("#<%= radWPA2.ClientID %>").is(':checked')) {
        $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWEP').hide();
        $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWPA').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWEP').hide();
        $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWPA').hide();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:RadioButton id="radNone" Text="None" Checked="True" meta:resourcekey="radNoneRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged"/>

    <asp:RadioButton id="radWEP" Text="WEP" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radWepRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged"/>

    <asp:RadioButton id="radWPA" Text="WPA" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radWpaRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged"/>

    <asp:RadioButton id="radWPA2" Text="WPA2" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radWpa2Rc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged"/>
</div>


<!-- show/hide these based on above -->
<div id="divRadioGroupKeyFormatWEP" style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:RadioButton id="radOpen" Text="Open" Checked="True" meta:resourcekey="radOpenRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat1" runat="server"/>
    <asp:RadioButton id="radShared" Text="Shared" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radSharedRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat1" runat="server"/>
</div>

<div id="divRadioGroupKeyFormatWPA" style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:RadioButton id="radTKIP" Text="TKIP" Checked="True" meta:resourcekey="radTkipRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat2" runat="server"/>
    <asp:RadioButton id="radAES" Text="AES" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radAesRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat2" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: It's always helpful, this being a client-side issue, to post **MARKUP AS SEEN BY THE BROWSER**.

Comment: $("#<%= radWEP.ClientID %>") Intermixing .NET variables in JS is a bad practice. It ensures the JS file can never be cached. Also, you're better off selecting class names, that can be controlled, over the insanity that is .NET's use of element IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're missing the parentheses. It seems to me that it should be: onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged()" or onclick="javascript:SecurityCheckedChanged()"

The first answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick) is interesting on how to hook events in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use RadioButtonList which is easy to find the selected value using jQuery selector -

`#id input:radio:checked`

[image]

```
<div style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="SecurityRadioButtonList" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value="" Selected="True" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="WEP" Value="WEP" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="WPA" Value="WPA" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="WPA2" Value="WPA2" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<!-- show/hide these based on above -->
<div id="divRadioGroupKeyFormatWEP" style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="radOpen" Text="Open" Checked="True"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="radShared" Text="Shared" Checked="False"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat1" runat="server" />
</div>

<div id="divRadioGroupKeyFormatWPA" style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="radTKIP" Text="TKIP" Checked="True"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat2" runat="server" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="radAES" Text="AES" Checked="False"
        GroupName="RadioGroupKeyFormat2" runat="server" />
</div>
```

### Script

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var wepDiv, wpaDiv;    
    $(function() {
        wepDiv = $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWEP');
        wpaDiv = $('#divRadioGroupKeyFormatWPA');
        wepDiv.hide();
        wpaDiv.hide();    
        $('#<%= SecurityRadioButtonList.ClientID %> input').click(function() {
            securityChange();
        });    
        securityChange();
    });

    function securityChange() {
        var value = $('#<%= SecurityRadioButtonList.ClientID %> input:radio:checked').val();
        if (value != undefined) {
            if (value == "WEP") {
                wepDiv.show();
                wpaDiv.hide();
            } else if (value == "WPA" || value == "WPA2") {
                wepDiv.hide();
                wpaDiv.show();
            } else {
                wepDiv.hide();
                wpaDiv.hide();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

### jsfiddle

Here is the generated code in [jsfiddle.net/9vg3bs77](http://jsfiddle.net/9vg3bs77/).