# What is better to use onclick attribute of html element or jquery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always use jquery event like:

```
$(element).on('click', function() {
    DoSomething();
});
```

But other way is exists - add "onclick" attribute to html element:

```
<button onclick="DoSomething()"></button>
```

Which way is better and why?

Comment: Most people will point to first way due to separation of concerns

Comment: First one looks easier to maintain and more flexible

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick

Comment: duplicate of [jQuery.click() vs onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Comment: the first way makes it easier to maintain code; it is recommended since it provides good modularity.

Comment: Thanks, link to jQuery.click() vs onClick give me all information that is required. Is exists standard code conventions for JS like W3C conventions for HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use the jquery because you want to separate your layout, functionality, and styling for easier readability and editing.