# link onclick vs. button onclick

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, section508

This is a fairly simple accessibility question.

Say we have a toggle link/button which, when clicked, toggles the mobile menu. Which is the more accessible format for such a button?

We have 4 total options, separated by

- `button` tag vs.
- `a` tag,

and

- `onclick` attribute vs.
- `$("#showMenu").on("click", function() { showMenu() } )`

**All Options**

1. `<a href="#" onclick="showMenu();"></a>`
2. `<button onclick="showMenu();"></button>`
3. `<a href="#" id="showMenu"></a>`

   - with `$("#showMenu").on("click",function() { showMenu() } );`
4. `<button id="showMenu"></button>`

   - with `$("#showMenu").on("click",function() { showMenu() } );`

**Pros and Cons**

I have read that, for best accessibility, the `<button>` tag should be used for javascript actions, and `<a>` tags for normal links. Unfortunately, I cannot find that article again.

Folks always say to "separate logic from content". My answer is: do you really think your Javascript `showMenu()` function will work without that link to trigger it? So, are you *really* separating logic from content?

Along those lines, I do like the idea of using event handlers to attach events, however, this makes the code **harder** to maintain in certain circumstances, not easier. If I later delete that link or change the ID or class, I will lose the functionality. The `onclick` attribute reminds me to tread carefully. If I have more than one link, or wish to be 508 compliant (see next paragraph), I will use an event handler.

The 508 standard demands that every onclick attribute be accompanied by an equivalent keyboard attribute. This drives me nuts, because keyboard users can trigger an onclick event through the  key, and are used to doing so for text links.* In addition, if you DO add an onkeyup event handler of any sort, you need to filter for the  key, etc. so that users don't get "stuck" on your link and become completely unable to browse throughout the rest of the site.

*See note: http://alistapart.com/article/popuplinks#section6

**My questions**

1. Is a `<button>` tag better for accessibility?
2. Why or why not?
3. Which of the 4 is the best for accessibility?

Please note that this question is similar to the following question, but I am much more interested in the `<button>` vs. `<a>` argument. Plus, the following question does not even mention accessibility, which is what I am primarily concerned with.
[jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of this is a matter of opinion, but to me, a link takes you somewhere while a button performs an action. In your case, if it were me, I would use a button. And I would use the onclick with it, so as you mentioned, to not lose track of it later.

So your option #2.

Comment: I'm with you in both respects, and I agree on #2 for most cases.

Answer (score 2):

"Keep it simple ... ask your *customers!"*

Personally, I think that, when you want to *"do* something," you should use a button.  (Keyboard-shortcuts for HTML *buttons* should require no additional code ...)

If you want to "*go* somewhere," that's the (only) right place for a hyperlink.

I don't expect a "button" to take me someplace, and I don't expect a "hyperlink" to do something.

Comment: In principle I agree with you, but I've had customers who want me to make hyperlink like buttons. As you say, ask the people who sign your paycheck.

Comment: Yup!  But if "the 508 Standard" is against their paycheck-prerogatives, you might be obliged to "educate" them.  So it goes ...  :->

Comment: As @rubix_revenge points out, the customer doesn't necessarily always understand the difference between a link and a button. Besides, I can style a link like a button, or a button like a link, really doesn't matter to me. I'm more worried about semantics and accessibility.

Comment: But the "508 standards," most unfortunately, *are* quite specific in that way.  "When in Rome, you must do as the Romans expect."  :-/