# JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY GET THE VALUE OF THE FIRST ROW

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the first value of the row in my html table when I click in each delete button...

The table is populated from SQL database...

the image below!

I will put only the necessary code:

[image]

HTML Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_delete" id="btn_delete" onclick="delete_function()">Delete</button>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delete_function() {
        var id = $('#clients tbody').find('td:first').text();
        alert(id);      
    }
</script>
```

If I click in any button I always receive the alert with same result:

114

How I can get the same id number value that exist in the same line of the button clicked??? I accept Javascript and Jquery advices

Comment: You can't use the same ID on each button.

Comment: Additionally, if you are outputing this info from a server side language, just include the id on the button with `data-id=114` and then you can easily get it with `$('.btn_delete').data('id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to  :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_delete" id="btn_delete" onclick="delete_function(this)">Delete</button>
```

Use     `first-child`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delete_function(obj) {
        var id = $(obj).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
        alert(id);      
    }
</script>
```

One thing to mention : you should not use onclick in the html :

```
$(".btn_delete").on('click',function (){
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
  alert(id); 

});
```

Comment: I think it will still always return the same value. He's getting the first child of the parent element. He needs to traverse from the button up.

Comment: @Leeish no . you send `this` in `delete_function(this)`

Comment: That's not what your code was initially. Your initial answer resulted in 114 each time as well.

Comment: @Leeish Edited right about  seconds after posting the first answer . I dont see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn_delete').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
    alert(id);
}
```

onClick is  always a bad idea.

[jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

[Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

Comment: I suggest you to use `closest`  rather than `parents`

Comment: Why? Is there a problem? It skips the self-check.

Comment: YES . there is a problem : `parents` :Travels up the DOM tree to the document’s root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it **then** filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied. closest doesnt do it. it travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector

Comment: Ah I didn't know that and was just reading up on it to see if it was headed towards depreciation or something.

Comment: No need for deprecations. they do the _same_ thing. but the way they do it is different.

Comment: Right, I was checking because you said to use closest. I thought it might be depreciated. I thought it headed up the DOM to the first one it finds, apparently like closest does. I didn't know that. I thought closest looked downward and not just upward too.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways you can go about doing this, but one way would be to set the `id` directly on the button itself so you don't have to traverse the DOM to get it.

```
<button class="delete" data-id="114">Delete</button>
```

Then, in your JavaScript

```
$('button.delete').on('click', function( e ) {
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question wasn't how can I change my HTML to get the data, it was how do I get the data from a cell. Hence the down vote. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Leeish yet you suggested it in a comment?

Comment: Correct. Not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You always get the same result because you are always getting the same element. To get the value related to the button that you pressed, you need to involve the button when you locate the element.

As you are using jQuery, you can use it to bind the events also. Remove the `onclick` attribute from the HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_delete" id="btn_delete">Delete</button>
```

In the event handler you use the button that was clicked (`this`) to locate the first cell in the same row:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#clients .btn_delete').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    alert(id);      
  }

});
```