# Click element Equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whats the equivalent of the below jquery code using javascript?

```
$("#id").on("click",function(event){alert(event.target.id);});
```

I know i can use the below code

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { alert(e.target.id)  }, false);
```

But i want to constrain it to a particular id and not the whole document.

Comment: `document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', function(e) { alert(e.target.id)  }, false)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.click() vs onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Comment: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): _The EventTarget.addEventListener() method registers the specified listener on the EventTarget it's called on. The event target may be an **Element** in a document, the **Document** itself, a **Window**, or **any other object that supports events** (such as XMLHttpRequest)._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click',
function(e) 
{
    alert(e.target.id);
}, false);
```

The last parameter is `useCapture`.

Reference - [W3SCHOOLS](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

`true` - the function is executed in the capturing phase.

`false` - the function is executed in the bubbling phase. **(Default)**

No need to worry as **it is optional** in all browsers now.

Comment: whats the significance of "false" at the end?? Pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

To attach an event handler on an element, selected by `id`, you can do:

```
document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
   alert(e.target.id)  
}, false);
```

**n.b.** the `false` at the end is an optional parameter bool for capture, from MDN:

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture.

Comment: whats the significance of "false" at the end?? Pls let me know

Comment: user capture, you can read the full docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Get element by id and attach event lister

```
document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
  alert(e.target.id) 
}, false);
```

Use of boolean at the last is optional. A Boolean value that specifies whether the event should be executed in the capturing or in the bubbling phase.

For more Information - [addEventListener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var id = document.getElementById("id");

id.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert("hi");
},false);
```