# How to pass a variable to a function inside JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++)
{                      
    buttons.append($("<button onclick='getJSON(i)'>"+i+"</button>"));
}
```

Now, passing i inside getJSON() function doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Other answerers already have described how you can do this.
However, I would recommend another way:

```
for (var i=1; i<=numPages;i++)
{          
    $("<button/>")
        .addClass('myClass')
        .attr('data-my-id', i)
        .text(i)
        .appendTo(buttons);
}

$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function() {
    getJSON($(this).attr('data-my-id'));
});
```

It will generate the following HTML:

```
<button class='myClass' data-my-id='1'>1</button>
<button class='myClass' data-my-id='2'>2</button>
<button class='myClass' data-my-id='3'>3</button>
<button class='myClass' data-my-id='4'>4</button>
etc.
```

Why is this approach better?

- Button is now generated using jQuery, but not from a string, which decreases a chance of error
- It uses jQuery events instead of `onclick` attribute
- Event delegation for convenient work with dynamically created elements
- Element HTML doesn't contain behaviour (event) - it stores data (id)

jQuery is slower than a native JavaScript, but it is important only if we talk about thousands of elements. Otherwise, it is more important that code can be easily written, read and supported.

Also, here is a good article which describes why you shouldn't use `onclick` attribute`:
[jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Comment: How can you compare these two approaches performance point of view?

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna JS for performance, jQuery for convenience :) I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you Yelder! I upvote your answer as well :) But also in debugging it is somewhat difficult since function attached to the element is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
buttons.append($("<button onclick='getJSON("+i+")'>"+i+"</button>"));
```

You need to concatenate is properly, the way you did for another `i`

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it was something dumb like this and I've tried a few variations but none worked.

Answer (score -1):

Pass i to the getJSON method as a variable. You have sent it as a string by mistakenly.

```
 for (var i=1;i<=numPages;i++)
 {          

    buttons.append($("<button onclick='getJSON("+i+")'>"+i+"</button>"));

 }
```