# getting url parameters - error in console

Tags: javascript

I get error in console on line `getUrlVars() {`

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>

document.getElementById('myelement').onclick = function() {
    function getUrlVars() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        console.log(url.substring(url.indexOf('?')));
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<a id="myelement" href="#">some link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Make sure substring function is running properly..

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava the substring function must runs properly

Comment: [And please read this stackoverflow answer on a related topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478/4903925)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, then note this: you have not placed the "end of command line marker" `;` in the `getUrlVars()` end, and neither on the `document.getElementById('myelement').onclick` line. Also, you are creating a function that creates a function, and that is un-necessary.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('myelement').onclick = function() {
       var url = window.location.href;
       console.log(url.substring(url.indexOf('?')));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the below JS,

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myelement').onclick = function getUrlVars() {
      var url = window.location.href;
      console.log(url.substring(url.indexOf('?')));
    }
  }
```

Changes:

a) will do any action after window load is complete

b) function getUrlVars is the function when click happens on the anchor tag

Here comes a [fiddle LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/6sr20o9k/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a small JS that allows you to get a parameter from the queryString based on the name.

```
<script>
    var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

How to use the script for a parameter:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(getUrlParameter("numeParametru "))
          alert(getUrlParameter("ParameterName"));
          var myParam = getUrlParameter("ParameterName");
          //do stuff;
    });
</script>
```

Like this, if the parameter exists, you can do whatever you would like to with it.