# Why does there exist many variations of the click event listener in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onclicklistener, event-listener

I have found four variations of this so far.

`addEventListener('click')` is the native method and performs best.

Then jQuery wraps it to be compatible with some obsolete browsers while reducing performance by an order of magnitude, with three different methods:

`on('click')`

`click()`

`onclick()`

Why does there exist so many? What is the history/reasoning behind their existence? And briefly, are there differences in their use cases or limitations to each?

Comment: There's a good explanation on this link http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html And you may also refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478/4885631

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have found four variations of this so far.

Well, no. Two of those are the DOM, not jQuery. There is no `addEventListener` or `onclick` on jQuery instances. They're on DOM elements.

So why does jQuery have both [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and `click`? Maybe [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) can tell us:

> `click`
>
> This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`

It's just a shortcut, seven characters instead of 11 (13 originally, see below), for when the event name is known at coding time (rather than runtime, when we might pass a variable into `on`). (There's also another form of `click`: If you call it without arguments, it triggers the event rather than hooking up a handler.)

You forgot [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind), which is an earlier version of `on`. `on` was added in v1.7 to combine the functionality of `bind`, [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate), and [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live). Retrofitting `bind` would have required breaking changes, and the word `bind` was increasingly coming to mean [something else entirely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). So they went with `on`, since the DOM uses the "on" prefix (`onclick`, `onmousemove`, `onfocus`, ...), both in DOM element properties you can assign functions to, and as attributes you can put code in in the markup.

jQuery also has [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one), which is similar to `on` but automatically removes the handler on first use.

Bottom line: All APIs evolve over time.