# How to add fontawesome spinner inside onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, font-awesome

So I have this code inside my php echo;

`<input type="submit" value="Send Love" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value=\'Sending Love…\';" />`

As you can see the text will change onclick and the button will be disabled and the form will be submitted. But what i'm trying to do is add a fontawesome spinner besides Sending so the button will have a spinner when its being submitted. I tried adding it but it doesn't show up and it breaks the output of the code; I also tried using `'\'\` like with the Sending but it still doesn't show up and the onclick functions are broken.

`<input type="submit" value="Send Love" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value=\'<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending Love…\';" />`

So anyone could help me fix this thing? Really want to add that spinner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using jQuery `click()` will make this easier and [better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Comment: @Chay22 can you walk me through with that? thanks

Comment: nevermind got it to work using with what you suggested, thanks for the nice suggestion @Chay22

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to take `<button ... >` for that. Try this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendLove(this);" > Send Love</button>

<script>
function sendLove(this1)
{
  //alert('asdasd');
  this1.disabled=true; 
  this1.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending Love…';
}
</script>
```

Hello, here is full-fledged working example..

https://jsbin.com/bezomapeba/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: It breaks the whole document since that code is inside my php.

Comment: i tried changing it to a button still the same, or there should be different code when its in button?

Comment: the revised one got `;" />` this besides the text and it doesn't change when clicked.

Comment: newly revised didnt load the entire page.

Answer (score 2):

Made it to work using Chay22's suggestion of using jquery click

Button:

```
<button type="submit" id="sendbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Send Love</button>`
```

Script:

```
$('#sendbtn').click(function(){
this.form.submit();
this.disabled=true;
this.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending Love…';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is of browser's part, cos he think it html and handle it, try to do that with js, `echo '<input type="submit" value="Send Love" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value=\'<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin">Sending Love…</i>\';>';`

[JavaScript's way](https://jsfiddle.net/ag2rL3zs/1/)

Comment: the output is broken, since it adds `Sending Love…';" />` outside the button and it doesn't function well.

Comment: the revised one didn't load the page since its already inside echo '';

Comment: the problem is of browser's part, cos he think it html and handle it, try to do that with js, `echo '<input type="submit" value="Send Love" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value=\'<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin">Sending Love…</i>\';>';`

Answer (score 1):

**Smallest, lightweight, and reusable**
We made a custom jQuery.fn:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    spin: function () {
        this.data("original-html", this.html());
        var i = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw" style="font-size:16px; margin-right:10px"></i>';
        this.html(i + this.html());
        this.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    },
    reset: function () {
        this.html(this.data("original-html"));
        this.attr("disabled", null);
    }
});
```

This can be used as follows:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var b = $(this);
    b.spin();
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        button: b,
        success: function (result) {
            // do something
            b.reset();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for today, but the best thing I found. Tip to anyone wondering how to use: throw it in it's own js file and include the script tag to it in your html after your script tag that imports jQuery. I also extended it to include `disableOnly: function()` as I like to disable other buttons on the form when posting, without sticking a spinner in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful and better. Add a div above your submit button

```
<div class="loading" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Progressing …</div>
```

or add button like below

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i style="display:none" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin loading"></i> Send Love</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#sendbtn").click(function(){  // your submit button id
      var isValid = document.querySelector('#myform')
      if (isValid.checkValidity())
        $(".loading").show();
   });
});
```