# Make JavaScript/HTML OnClick Work on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given an HTML page full of `onclick`s and more being added by JavaScript later on, how would one make these functions fire on touch events on iOS as well?

For example:

```
<div onclick='dosomething();'></div>
```

Preferably just one piece of JS that runs through the page add touch events. JQuery is fine.

Comment: [You should avoid the `onClick` attributes in your html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478/4202224). While using jQuery use the `.on()` or `.click()` method. So you can use `.on('click touch')` to register event-handler

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

[MDN Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Add the event handlers like so.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:solid black 1px;">
  Your browser does not support canvas element.
</canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="startup()">Initialize</button>
<br>
Log: <pre id="log" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></pre>
```

-

```
function startup() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
  log("initialized.");
}
```

Then you can create the functions handleStart, handleEnd etc to do what ever.