# Return a specific DOM element from 'click' event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function viewdwable(dwableid) {
  $("#modal-body2").html('Temporary loading message..');
  $("#myModal").fadeIn(300);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'scripts/viewdwablehome.php',
    data: { "currentNumber": dwableid, "usersid": usersid },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#modal-body2').html(data['cntent12']);
    }
  });    
}
```

This activates when clicked:

```
<div class="postfeed2" onclick="javascript:return viewdwable(' . $id . ');">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:return like(' . strip_tags($id) . ');">Text linked here</a>
</div>
```

The problem is I have another onclick link within the div. When that onclick is clicked I don't want it to also fire the div onclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire your function inside a [proper event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478/4202224), so you can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) for the inner element. This will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM.

```
$('.postfeed2').on('click', function(){
    alert('clicked outer');
});

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('clicked inner');
});
```

---

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hzmdsa3m/)

Comment: The div postfeed2 is part of an array which means it appears multiple times and why I didn't use this format. Do you have an example using onclick specifically?

Comment: Instead of have the variable `$id` as a function parameter you can attach it as e.g. a ´data-´ attribute and referencing to it inside the event-handler

Comment: Could you show me how to add it and particularly reference it. I've never used that kind of attribute before. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben Have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kqLsv1sh/) example. You can acces the data-attribut with `.data('')`.

Comment: Yep @empiric think I can work it out from there. Market correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stopPropagation`.

Read more about `event.stopPropagation()`

- https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation