# Problems with .append() content containing quotes and dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quotes

I want to add a HTML code to a table using `.append(SOMET HTML CODE)`.

Into my `<tr>` I want to implement an `onclick()` event - which calls a function -, BUT it seems that there are some problems with the quotes AND with the content itself (because the content is a soccer players name and this name contains a dot like: *`M**.** Neuer`*)

My **jQuery** looks like this:

```
$('.player_table').append('<tr id="'+pos+players.id+'" costsForThisPlayer="12.2" class="goalKepperRow" onclick="addGoalkeeperByClickEvent("'+players.name+'", "gk1", 12.2)><td>something</td></tr>');
```

and my **HTML** looks really strange then

```
<tr id="gk149" costsforthisplayer="12.2" class="goalKepperRow" onclick="addGoalkeeperByClickEvent(" m.hitz",="" "gk1",="" 12.2)=""><td>something</td></tr>
```

and this is the part where is crashed:

```
onclick="addGoalkeeperByClickEvent(" m.hitz",="" "gk1",="" 12.2)="">
```

how I have to change my jquery part correctly?

Comment: Escape problematic quotes by prefixing \.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML string contains double quotes within double quotes.
You have use single quotes and escape them:

```
'... onclick="addGoalkeeperByClickEvent(\''+players.name+'\', \'gk1\', 12.2)"...'
// or:
'... onclick=\'addGoalkeeperByClickEvent("'+players.name+'", "gk1", 12.2);\'...'
```

---

On a side note:

1. `costsForThisPlayer` is not a [valid HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). Use [**`data-*`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes to store custom values.
2. Using an `onClick` attribute [is not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick). You should consider setting a `.click()` event handler with jQuery.

   Since your content is added dynamically, you'll have to delegate `click` event on the table using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

   ```
   $('.player_table').on('click', `.goalKepperRow`, function(){
       var costsForThisPlayer = $(this).attr('data-costsForThisPlayer');
       var playerName = $(this).attr('data-name');
       var something = $(this).attr('data-something');
       // all the values that you're passing to the onClick function are here
       // ... the rest of your addGoalkeeperByClickEvent() method ...
   });
   ```

   Then your HTML creation part would be:

   ```
   $('<tr/>').attr({
     'id'                      : pos+players.id,
     'class'                   : "goalKepperRow",
     'data-costsForThisPlayer' : "12.2",
     'data-name'               : players.name,
     'data-something'          : "gk1"
   })
   .append('<td>something</td>')
   .appendTo('.player_table');
   ```

Comment: I suggest to using syntax \`text ${string}` for easy reading.

Comment: thx for your help AND thx for your extra side note, but the functions where i want to call are based on values from a database, thats why i tried it with an onClick() at the HTML part... (i hope i descripbed it good enough hehe)

Comment: @nbg15, then why not use `data-*` attributes to store database values for each element?