# Trigger a click event with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a ul with let's say 10 li elements. Inside every li elemenet there is img that on click is opened in modal. I want to make a function that when you send someone a link to specific img (let say www.aaa.com/#/image/3) to open the third image. So far I don't have any success. On the list I've got:  `$(document).on('click', 'li img', function(){ ... }`
Here is the question how to simulate specific img click event, cuz I've made this modal to work with `this`, it's not very specific like number 3 from the url.

ps I don't want to use server side, that's why I'm using #.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.click() vs onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick for click functions in both javascript and jquery

Comment: aren't you missing 'ready' in your code:
$(document).on('click', 'li img', function(){ ... }

Comment: I need to make this clarifications - 
output.jsbin.com/lipahudaxe (on the top right there is edit in jsbin). And the thing that I'm trying right now is when you receive the link, try to trigger click on the specific img and not copy paste the code. I'm doing this in other function, called on the loading of the site: function setupImage (imgIndex) { .... var total = $('ul.images-list li').length + 1; if(imgIndex <= total) { $('li img').eq(imgIndex).trigger('click'); } } Because of the using of hashes and other function, the problem was not exact same as in the mentioned by Binit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `document.location.hash` to get the current `hash` from the link, and if there is a hash, and it's an image - trigger the `click` on that image:

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  var hash = document.location.hash;
  if (hash) { // check if hash exists
    m = hash.match(/#\/image\/(\d+)/) // check the structure
    if (m) {
      $('ul#specific-ul li img').eq(m[1] - 1).click() // trigger click on the relevant image
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But when you receive a link, I've made a simple switch method to check what is the link and if it's a image, it should be opened modal with that image. The thing is that `$('li img').eq(imgIndex).trigger('click');` doesn't work. I don't know why. I've got attached event listener to the li img, but it still doesn't make the click event :|

Comment: Can you create an example of what you are doing? Without a working example it will be hard to help

Comment: https://output.jsbin.com/lipahudaxe (on the top right there is edit in jsbin). And the thing that I'm trying right now is when you receive the link, try to trigger click on the specific img and not copy paste the code. I'm doing this in other function, called on the loading of the site: `function setupImage (imgIndex) {
    ....
    var total = $('ul.images-list li').length + 1;
    if(imgIndex <= total) {
         $('li img').eq(imgIndex).trigger('click');
    }
       
}`

Comment: Read again my code and see what what is the differences between what I wrote and where you put the code inside your page.

Comment: It doesn't work, mate, I don't know why :| It's something very stupid and lame, cuz I've tried it :| Btw I've added some information in the comment above

Comment: Copy the **exact** code I wrote and put it in you javascript source (**not** inside some other function).

Comment: Did you check and fix?

Comment: It works, but there is question - why? When it's in function - doesn't work, when it's not it works? Is there something like attaching event handler is not global and other functions can't use it?

Comment: You put it inside the `click` event - so the will not work **until** you click on the element.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger click event you use `$('#image3').trigger('click')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the ID attribute. if you have added your li in a loop thn take a variable append it with id in loop. don't forget to do variable++.

When you will click on the image like with id = image5
you can use this 
`$("#image5").click(function(){
       // Do something
});`