# Update button onClick url from AJAX in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple form with a "Submit" button and an additional "Add" button in blade template. On form submit there is an ajax callback to a controller which validates provided value. Based on the returned result from the controller, I'd like to change the "Add" button onClick event. Here is blade snip:

```
<button id="theId" type="button" >Add</button>
```

Relevant ajax pice:

```
$.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(result){
           //Update onClick for the add button
           addButton.onclick=function () {
               //location.href = 'www.example.com';
               window.location="www.example.com";
           };
           addButton.html("aNewName");
        }
}
```

Based on all the sources either location.href or window.location should redirect me to a different page (in my case just a different subpage) but it does not. After hours of research I thought that I get a wrong button or sth is wrong with the ajax itself but then I added addButton.html line and this works well. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Try the `click()` function of jQuery : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick

Comment: How do you set `addButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the button, remove eventually previous click events, add the new event using the http/https prefix, change the text of the button

```
success: function(result){
   var button = document.querySelector('#theId');
   button.addEventListener('click', function () {
       window.location = 'https://www.google.it';
   });
   button.innerHTML = "my new button text";
}
```

Comment: I got: "Uncaught TypeError: addButton.removeEventListener is not a function"

Comment: sorry I was still pointing to your old code, that variable should be "button" I already updated the code

Comment: What should I pass as the second argument to the removeEventListener? An empty function?

Comment: Works, an empty function it was. Please update your answer so I could accept it.

Comment: That should be the old function you used but in this case also setting it to null should be ok if you are using it only there. Can you try with the new changed code too please?

Comment: This is not working, "TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null". Btw: As I showed in my example, there was no onClick action until the ajax callback.

Comment: if there is not you can just use the add event listener omitting that code

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Registering_on-event_handlers, a handler registered via an on* attribute will be available via the corresponding on* property, but not the other way around.

What this means is that the `onclick` attribute of the div remains the old event handler in HTML.
To keep sanity, always register event listeners with the `addEventListener` method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set a jQuery object's `onclick` property to a function, which is not the right way to set a click event handler in jQuery.

You should use the jQuery object's [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method to set a click handler. And use the [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method to remove the previous handler:

```
addButton.off('click');
addButton.click(function () {
  window.location="https://www.example.com";
})
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hhLga30g/)

Comment: Odd, this does not work for me. I click the "Add" button and nothing happens

Comment: The example fiddle doesn't redirect the page it logs a string in the console to show that the handler has changed

Comment: JsFiddle doesn't let you share fiddles where the window location gets changed, so I can't show you, but just put this `window.location="https://www.example.com";` inside the click handler. It works.