# no href, onclick function for html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not too advanced in html and javascript. I am just trying to understand, how skyscanner search flights button works. There is no `onclick event` or `function` associated with it. Can anyone help me please?

```
<button class="fss-bpk-button fss-bpk-button--large js-search-button" tabindex="1" type="button">
    <span class="bpk-text">Search flights</span>
    <span class="bpk-icon-lg bpk-icon-pointer bpk-icon-lg--align-to-button"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Comment: They're just using event listeners bound to the button, i.e. `Element.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no onclick event or function associated with it.

There probably is, it's just:

1. Added with JavaScript code, not with markup; and/or
2. On an ancestor element

Most likely #1.

Re #1: Using `onclick` attributes and such is just one way to put an event handler on a button, and it's a way that's best avoided. Instead, you use modern event handling via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (or `attachEvent` on old IE). This might be using the DOM directly, or via a library like jQuery, MooTools, React, Vue, ...

Example using the DOM directly:

```js
document.querySelector(".my-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Click!");
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="my-button">Click Me</button>
```

Re #2: `click` events *bubble* from the element on which the user clicked to that element's ancestor elements, all the way up to the document element (`html`). So you can handle that event on an ancestor element, rather than on the button itself. Handling events on an ancestor element is sometimes called "event delegation."

Example:

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Click on '" + e.target.textContent + "'!");
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This div contains two buttons. The event handler is on the div, not the buttons.
  <div>
    <button type="button">One</button>
    <button type="button">Two</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is probably called on a button holding "js-search-button" class. There is no need to insert onevent handlers within the HTML element if you can use any script to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach events using `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.

Below way to `attach click event to static element`.

```
$('button[class="fss-bpk-button fss-bpk-button--large js-search-button"]').click(function(){
  console.log("clicked!!!");
});
```

If your element is `dynamic` then you need to `delegate event`.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[class="fss-bpk-button fss-bpk-button--large js-search-button"]', function(){
  console.log("clicked!!!");
});
```

Hope this will help you.