# Make the div's opacity=1 when it is clicked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML-

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p >Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright" >
    <img class="integration" src="integrations-image.png" width="100%" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS used for the div-

```
.border{
  border-left:6px solid #3793EE;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
  }
div.JShover{
    height:50%;
    text-align: left;
    opacity:0.5;

}
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 700px;
}
.floatleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;  
}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

When the floatleft divs JShover is clicked the opacity should be 1. Otherwise it should 0.5.
JavaScript used-

```
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".JShover").click(function() {
    this.style.opacity = 1
});
</script>
```

In the result the JShover divs have an opacity of 0.5 (since it is in the CSS) but when I click on it, the opacity does not change to 1. Is there any error in my code or implementation?

Comment: Very trivial question... also you have a typo at `height:100px`, use `=`.

Comment: @PredatorIWD Thanks, I corrected that. I have recently started with web design, so yes I apologize for the nature of the question. Is it that easy? Could you please help me out then :)

Comment: You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478) answer for multiple ways to achieve your effect.

Comment: Oops that was only here while posting the question, in my code it was closed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example do it like this:

```
$(".JShover").click(function() {
    this.style.opacity = 1
});
```

Also add `opacity: 0.5;` to your `div.JShover` element in css.

Working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/71973avt/2/).

Edit:

First, be sure to have jQuery on your site either with having and linking a local copy or linking it inside your `<head>` like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And second be sure to put your js code for changing opacity below the linked jQuery library, for example below or at the end of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: I did try it, thanks. So the JS goes into the <script type="text/javascript"> tag yes?

Comment: @Yohanelly Correct.

Comment: Hi, I have done so but the text does not change its opacity when clicked. I have updated the question, if you could please have a look.

Comment: @Yohanelly You didn't close the `<script>` tag properly.

Comment: Oops that was only here while posting the question, in my code it was closed properly. Everything else seems fine, did i do something incorrect because i cant seem to find the error.

Comment: Do I need to add this to the script other than type="text/javascript" <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156198/discussion-between-yohanelly-and-predatoriwd).

Answer (score 1):

**Here is your html**

```
<div class='floatleft'>
Hello..... :)
</div>
```

**Here is your CSS**

```
 .floatleft{
    background-color:red;
    opacity:0;
    }
```

**Here is your JS**

```
$('.floatleft').click(function(){
$(this).css('opacity','1')
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you @LSKhan, I have updated my code in the question. When i click on the text, the opacity does not change to 1. Could you please help me out?

Comment: did you get you solution from @PredatorIWD? or i help you?

Comment: Hey, I have got it. But I am still trying to figure out how to make the previously clicked div to go back to its previous opacity of 0.3 when the next div is clicked? Code- https://jsfiddle.net/71973avt/5/

Comment: you mean you want to make the clicked element opacity 1 and others to 0.5?rite?

Comment: Hey I got it, figured it out. Had to add   $(".JShover").css('opacity', '0.2'); Do you know how to make a good looking navigation bar at the top of the webpage? I can send you a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve if thats okay. Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156207/discussion-between-yohanelly-and-lskhan).

Comment: yeah i can make it let me see your your screenshot first