# Code a HTML button to link to a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to get a button written in HTML to link to a separate JavaScript file when it is clicked, the button in question is coded below

```
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Submit" />
```

I am using the Brackets code editor, and the js file I want to be linked is in the same project as my HTML code, if that helps at all

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean link? Like take the user to the browser? Or call a Javascript function?

Comment: call a javascript function, sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 1):

Load the script into the page with a [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) element.

Keep your code in a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) instead of simply running the whole thing with the script is loaded.

Find the button in the DOM (e.g. with [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) and bind the function as a click event listener with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean link, I would use an `<a>` (anchor) tag which has an attribute `href` which is the reference. Therefore, you could use:

`<a href="http://example.com/public/js/script.js">Link to JS</a>`

Or perhaps you meant the `onclick` attribute which would be:
`<input type="button" id="clickme" onclick="myfunction()" value="Submit" />`

However, as was pointed out, this is not best practice either.

[jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Provides some options and reinforces the idea that `onclick` is not the best way to trigger a Javascript function.

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attributes. They have nasty gotchas and fail to separate concerns.

Comment: W3Schools is not a good reference. It is frequently misleading, somethings outright wrong, and almost never an example of best practices.

Comment: @Quentin, this is true, I would generally use eventListeners like you mentioned, but was trying to target the specific question. Personally, I'd use jQuery `.click` or `.on('click'...` since my projects nearly all utilize jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Just link your js script to a page by:

```
<script src="js/button.js"></script>
```

and then just call action in that scripts through the class or id.

```
 <button id="btnShow"><h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Expand</h1></button>
 <p class="p1">Test</p1>
```

That's a jQuery not js, but anyway a good example as I think

```
$('#btnShow').click(function(){
 $('.p1').show();
});
```