# onClick not called for button (html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html fragmentRow is as below, which has a `<a>` and a

```
<a href="onLoadShowRoutesView?routeIdnpk=${param.routeIdnpk}">
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-default btn-flat pull-right" value="${param.publishOrUnPublishValue}"
        name="${param.publishOrUnPublishName}"
        id="${param.publishOrUnPublishName}"
        onclick="${param.publishOrUnPublishOnClick}"
        data-val="${param.routeIdnpk}" style="margin-top: 6px;">
  </div>                        
</a>
```

I am including fragmentRow.jsp like this

```
<jsp:include page="fragmentListRouteItem.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="routeIdnpk"
    value="${childRouteViewPojo.routeIdnpk}" />
  <jsp:param name="publishOrUnPublishValue" value="Publish" />
  <jsp:param name="publishOrUnPublishName" value="Publish" />
  <jsp:param name="publishOrUnPublishOnClick" value="onPublish" />
</jsp:include>
```

And I have a `ajax` that is called `onclick` of the button

```
$('#unPublish').click(
  function() {
    var routeIdnpk = $(this).prev().val();
    $.ajax({
      type : "Get",
      url : "unpublishRoute",
      data : {
        routeIdnpk : routeIdnpk 
      },
      success : function(response) {
        response = successAction(response);
      },
      error : function(e) {
        ajaxGlobalErrorResponseWithTitleAndMessage("Unable to Unpublish",
      "The unpublish operation failed, please try again");
      }
    });
  });
```

When I click on the button, `onLoadShowRoutesView` gets called instead of  **$('#unPublish').click(**

I have tried `$('#unPublish').click(` and `onClick="unPublish", function unPublish()` too. Still the `href of <a>` gets called. Is there a way to override the main div `<a href>` and instead call the caller of the button on click ?

I have read thru [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick), and other links too. But unable to find a fix for the issue.

Now I know I am missing something very basic here.

**Edit 1** : I have tried

```
<div onclick="location.href='onLoadShowRoutesView?routeIdnpk=${param.routeIdnpk}';">
```

Still the onLoadShowRoutesView gets called even when I click the button

**Edit 2** @zakaria-acharki : I also added

```
function onUnPublish () {
    var routeIdnpk = $(this).prev().val();

            $.ajax({
        }) ;
}

function publish () {
    var routeIdnpk = $(this).prev().val();
    $.ajax({
        }) ;
}
```

Yet same result

Comment: Are you sure there's an element with id `unPublish`.

Comment: Sometimes, I get an error because I don't give `event` to my function is `onClick`, try to set `function unPublish(evt)` and `onClick={(evt) => {this.unPublish(evt)}}`

Comment: tried that .. it still defaults to <a href> instead of the onclick

Comment: I am reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: You want it execute the function of `<a>` and `onClick` ?

Comment: Try `<a href="onLoadShowRoutesView?routeIdnpk=${param.routeIdnpk}" id="unPublish">`. There is no `id` on the `a` tag, therefore you call the function on `undefined` ...

Comment: @zakaria-acharki i tried adding the functions also see **Edit 2**

Comment: @MarkFrankli that is not what I want. I want the button onClick to be called when I click the button

Comment: you want to to preventDefault? or am i reading it wrong?

Comment: @Stender, I have a <input type=button inside of <a, I am not able to get the button onclick event.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki its the typo. thanks..

Comment: I would either turn the input into a `<button`  or remove the `<a`; OR put the `onclick` on the `<a`

Comment: Good luck @Siddharth, you're welcome

Comment: @NappingRabbit I'll try the <a onclick and report back

Answer (score 1):

With help from @zakaria-acharki, What worked for me was the below. Some typos and 'ondblclick' with the parent `div`

**1**

```
$('#unPublish').click(
        function() {
            var routeIdnpk = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({

        });
$('#Publish').click(
        function() {
            var routeIdnpk = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({

        });
```

**2**

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-small btn-default btn-flat pull-right"
        value="${param.routeIdnpk}"
        name="${param.publishOrUnPublishName}"
        id="${param.publishOrUnPublishName}" style="margin-top: 6px;">${param.publishOrUnPublishValue}</button>
```

**3**

```
<div
    ondblclick="location.href='onLoadShowRoutesView?routeIdnpk=${param.routeIdnpk}';">
```

**EDIT**

> $('#unPublish').click(
>   works only for the first button
>
> $('button[name="unPublish"]').click(function(){
>   this worked for all the buttons

Today : I learnt the value of `button[name="something"]`

Answer (score 0):

try edit your code a little bit like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="yourFunction()"></a>
```

you can add your onclick function on your element or adding the function dynamically