# C# - How to pass html input value to url.Action

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an `input` and a `button`. input's value supposed to be passed to `@url.Action` like description in code below:

```
<input class="in-class" id="textbox" type="text" runat="server" />
<button class="btn-class" id="press" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {id = /*Value Of textbox*/ })'" >click here</button>
```

As I mentioned in code, `/*Value Of textbox*/` should be input's current value.

Comment: use a form for this.

Comment: you can't. you need to write javascript for this

Comment: Can you post the code for the controller action?

Answer (score 2):

Change the href value with jQuery or JavaScript like this:

```
     <button class="btn-class" id="press" type="button" onclick="changeHref()" >click here</button>

   function changeHref(){
         var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
         var txtVal = $('#textbox').val();
         window.location.href = url + '/?txtVal=' + txtVal;
   }
```

Comment: Forgot the query string. You'll have to add ?txtVal= after the '/'. I updated the code

Comment: Is it hitting the Index method inside the Home controller? Put a breakpoint inside the method to see if you even go back to the server. If not, then it's the url that's being set.

Comment: they both wont hit breakpoint, in the first place ('/') it opens just txtVal as a link, but when I Use '/?txtVal=' nothing happens.

Comment: Try, window.location.href = url + '?id=' + txtVal;

Comment: use post or get instead of window.location then: $.post(url, {txtVal: txtVal});

Comment: post or get is for ajax. window.location is fine if he wants to navigate to a new page.

Comment: Your url will be wrong. You can't use @url.Action in js function. Try to send url.action as parameter from html onclick="changeHref(url.action(controller, action))"

Answer (score 2):

I use this form

`<input type="text" id="txtValue" />
 <input type="button" value="Detail" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Home")?Value=' + $('#txtValue').val()" />`

or you cant write this in jquery function.

Comment: this should work but i personally would recommend breaking out into a function as well.

Answer (score 1):

I preferred using jQuery `click` handler since you have button ID and following [standard event registration model to separate HTML & JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick):

**HTML**

```
<input class="in-class" id="textbox" type="text" />
<button class="btn-class" id="press" type="button">click here</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#press').click(function () {
   var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
   var textValue = $('#textbox').val();

   window.location.href = url + '?id=' + textValue;
});
```

**PS:** No need to use `runat="server"` attribute in MVC since Razor doesn't require it.