# &times; added from javascript not clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I've added html content from javascript like this:

```js
var response = { message: "sample messsage" };

$('#main-content').append(
    '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'+
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss=alert">'+
    '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+
    '<span class="sr-only">Close</span>'+
    '</button>'+response.message+
    '</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main-content"></div>
```

The html code append works correctly but the close X  not working. I've looked everywhere still don't get the solution.

Any kind of suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: There's a high chance the elements with class `"close"` are selected on page load/ready and the handler attached at that moment. You either need to attach the handler to parent container with more elaborate selector, or attach handler manually after creation

Comment: It will be so helpful to have jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: @Kaddath in fact, a more basic question is if there is even code for the close button to begin with.

Comment: @VLAZ you're right, maybe i'm wrong to assume something like this wouldn't come from a 4K user, but i did

Comment: @Kaddath I'm new to javascript and event binding so i've posted here to get some idea about what's going wrong.

Comment: @SagarGautam do you have other elements in your page with `class="close"` that close correctly?

Comment: @Kaddath I've added class `closeLink` and then removed content on button click event. Now, it's work fine. Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you expect it to be. But to have something clickable you need to add `onclick="clickevent()"`

Also you need to add a `function` in respond to `onclick`, which is `clickevent()` on the example shown:

```
function clickevent() {
    $('#main-content').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'+
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss=alert">'+
    '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+
    '<span class="sr-only">Close</span>'+
    '</button>'+
    '</div>'
);
}
```

Note that `.html` set the html element of the selected which in the example was `$('#main-content')`.

See the following snippet:

```js
var response = { message: "sample messsage" };

$('#main-content').append(
    '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'+
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss=alert">'+
    '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+
    '<span class="sr-only">Close</span>'+
    '</button>'+response.message+
    '</div>'
);

function clickevent() {
    $('#main-content').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'+
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss=alert">'+
    '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+
    '<span class="sr-only">Close</span>'+
    '</button>'+
    '</div>'
);
}
```

```css
.alert{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main-content" onclick="clickevent()"></div>
```

Refer to [`onclick()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) and difference between [`.click()` with `.onclick()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the js file is loaded before you add your elements to the html file.
You could add the elements to your html file and .hide() them at the beginning.
When you need them just .show() the elements.